# C# code won't compile. No implicit conversion between null and int

Tags: c#, string, null, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable types and the ternary operator: why is `? 10 : null` forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work)

Why doesn't this work? Seems like valid code.

```
  string cert = ddCovCert.SelectedValue;
  int? x = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cert)) ? null: int.Parse(cert);
  Display(x);
```

How should I code this? The method takes a Nullable. If the drop down has a string selected I need to parse that into an int otherwise I want to pass null to the method.

Comment: Duplicate - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work

Comment: Also for more information, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220250/in-c-why-cant-a-conditional-operator-implicitly-cast-to-a-nullable-type

Comment: Thanks Andrew Hare. Looks like this behavior is specific to the ternary operator (could use traditional if statement to avoid if desired). Looks like there are some other duplicates on SO, and in my opinion, this is poor API design on the part of Microsoft.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

```
int? x = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cert) ? (int?)null : int.Parse(cert);
```

Comment: so weird that you need to cast null.. why couldn't null be a universal type?

Comment: this is also possible: `int? x = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cert) ? null : (int?)int.Parse(cert);`

Answer (score 10):

I've come across the same thing ... I usually just cast the null to (int?)

```
int? x = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cert)) ? (int?)null: int.Parse(cert);
```