# Are there any good reasons why ternaries in C# are limited?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

Fails:

```
object o = ((1==2) ? 1 : "test");
```

Succeeds:

```
object o;
if (1 == 2)
{
    o = 1;
}
else
{
    o = "test";
}
```

The error in the first statement is:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'string'.

Why does there need to be though, I'm assigning those values to a variable of type object.

**Edit:** The example above is trivial, yes, but there are examples where this would be quite helpful:

```
int? subscriptionID; // comes in as a parameter

EntityParameter p1 = new EntityParameter("SubscriptionID", DbType.Int32)
{
    Value = ((subscriptionID == null) ? DBNull.Value : subscriptionID),
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the typo in your question's title, thanks. I don't have enough reputation to edit it myself.

Comment: In your second example you could write: Value = subscriptionID ?? DBNull.Value;

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C# why can't a conditional operator implicitly cast to a nullable type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220250/in-c-sharp-why-cant-a-conditional-operator-implicitly-cast-to-a-nullable-type)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use:

```
object o = ((1==2) ? (object)1 : "test");
```

The issue is that the return type of the conditional operator cannot be un-ambiguously determined. That is to say, between int and string, there is no best choice. The compiler will always use the type of the true expression, and implicitly cast the false expression if necessary.

**Edit:**
In you second example:

```
int? subscriptionID; // comes in as a parameter

EntityParameter p1 = new EntityParameter("SubscriptionID", DbType.Int32)
{
    Value = subscriptionID.HasValue ? (object)subscriptionID : DBNull.Value,
}
```

**PS:**
That is not called the 'ternary operator.'  It *is* a ternary operator, but it is called the 'conditional operator.'

Comment: To elaborate, `1` is a primitive type, so you have to cast it to an object before you assign it.

Comment: Do primitives inherit object in C#?

Comment: @Wells they inherit from ValueType, and because you're casting it to an object there is some boxing going on there.

Comment: The type of a ternary conditional is always the strong type of the true value. The false value is implicitly cast to that type.

Answer (score 15):

Though the other answers are *correct*, in the sense that they make true and relevant statements, there are some subtle points of language design here that haven't been expressed yet.  Many different factors contribute to the current design of the conditional operator.

First, it is desirable for as many expressions as possible to have an unambiguous type that can be determined solely from the contents of the expression. This is desirable for several reasons.  For example: it makes building an IntelliSense engine much easier.  You type `x.M(some-expression.` and IntelliSense needs to be able to analyze *some-expression*, determine its type, and produce a dropdown BEFORE IntelliSense knows what method x.M refers to. IntelliSense cannot know what x.M refers to for sure if M is overloaded until it sees all the arguments, but you haven't typed in even the first argument yet.

Second, we prefer type information to flow "from inside to outside", because of precisely the scenario I just mentioned: overload resolution. Consider the following:

```
void M(object x) {}
void M(int x) {}
void M(string x) {}
...
M(b ? 1 : "hello");
```

What should this do? Should it call the object overload? Should it sometimes call the string overload and sometimes call the int overload? What if you had another overload, say `M(IComparable x)` -- when do you pick it?

Things get very complicated when type information "flows both ways". Saying "I'm assigning this thing to a variable of type object, therefore the compiler should know that it's OK to choose object as the type" doesn't wash; it's often the case that *we don't know the type of the variable you're assigning to because that's what we're in the process of attempting to figure out*. Overload resolution is exactly the process of working out the types of the parameters, which are the variables to which you are assigning the arguments, from the types of the arguments. If the types of the arguments depend on the types to which they're being assigned, then we have a circularity in our reasoning.

Type information does "flow both ways" for lambda expressions; implementing that efficiently took me the better part of a year.  I've written a long series of articles describing some of the difficulties in designing and implementing a compiler that can do analysis where type information flows into complex expressions based on the context in which the expression is possibly being used; part one is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx

You might say "well, OK, I see why the fact that I'm assigning to object cannot be safely used by the compiler, and I see why it's necessary for the expression to have an unambiguous type, but why isn't the type of the expression object, since both int and string are convertible to object?"  This brings me to my third point:

Third, one of the subtle but consistently-applied design principles of C# is "don't produce types by magic". When given a list of expressions from which we must determine a type, *the type we determine is always in the list somewhere*. We never magic up a new type and choose it for you; the type you get is always one that you gave us to choose from. If you say to find the best type in a set of types, we find the best type IN that set of types.  In the set {int, string}, there is no best common type, the way there is in, say, "Animal, Turtle, Mammal, Wallaby".  This design decision applies to the conditional operator, to type inference unification scenarios, to inference of implicitly typed array types, and so on.

The reason for this design decision is that it makes it easier for ordinary humans to work out what the compiler is going to do in any given situation where a best type must be determined; if you know that a type that is right there, staring you in the face, is going to be chosen then it is a lot easier to work out what is going to happen.

It also avoids us having to work out a lot of complex rules about what's the best common type of a set of types when there are conflicts. Suppose you have types {Foo, Bar}, where both classes implement IBlah, and both classes inherit from Baz. Which is the best common type, IBlah, that both implement, or Baz, that both extend?  We don't want to have to answer this question; we want to avoid it entirely.

Finally, I note that the C# compiler actually gets the determination of the types subtly wrong in some obscure cases. My first article about that is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx

It's arguable that in fact the compiler does it right and the spec is wrong; the implementation design is in my opinion better than the spec'd design.

Anyway, that's just a few reasons for the design of this particular aspect of the ternary operator. There are other subtleties here, for instance, how the CLR verifier determines whether a given set of branching paths are guaranteed to leave the correct type on the stack in all possible paths. Discussing that in detail would take me rather far afield.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I just read the first paragraph and was wondering if intellisense can identify the right overload when you type? For instance if I have a method called Perform, that can take 1 argument only of types, string, int, float, Size, etc, would intellisense scroll to the right overload info tooltip using the type I use? So if I use Perform (myString), it would immediately show the tooltip for Perform (string)? Right now it's only scrolling when the number of arguments change.

Answer (score 2):

Why is feature X this way is often a very hard question to answer.  It's much easier to answer the actual behavior.

My educated guess as to why.  The conditional operator is allowed to succinctly and tersely use a boolean expression to pick between 2 related values.  They must be related because they are being used in a single location.  If the user instead picks 2 unrelated values perhaps the had a subtle typo / bug in there code and the compiler is better off alerting them to this rather than implicitly casting to object.  Which may be something they did not expect.

Answer (score 0):

"int" is a primitive type, not an object while "string" is considered more of a "primitive object".  When you do something like "object o = 1", you're actually boxing the "int" to an "Int32".  Here's a link to an article about boxing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx

Generally, boxing should be avoided due to performance loses that are hard to trace.

When you use a ternary expression, the compiler does not look at the assignment variable at all to determine what the final type is.  To break down your original statement into what the compiler is doing:

Statement:
object o = ((1==2) ? 1 : "test");

Compiler:

1. What are the types of "1" and "test" in '((1==2) ? 1 : "test")'?  Do they match?
2. Does the final type from #1 match the assignment operator type for 'object o'?

Since the compiler doesn't evaluate #2 until #1 is done, it fails.