# C# Return value of a property which is nullable

Tags: c#, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type result with Ternary operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815033/type-result-with-ternary-operator-in-c)

I ran into this scenario, and there doesn't seem to be a natural way to return a nullable int. The code below gives compilation error because the ternary operator doesn't like null.

```
public int? userId
{
    get
    {
        int rv;
        return int.TryParse(userIdString, out rv) ? rv : null;
    }
}
```

So you (or just me) really have to go all the way and spell it all out:

```
public int? userId
{
    get
    {
        int id;
        if(int.TryParse(userIdString, out id)){
           return id;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Is there a more natural way of instantiating a nullable, to make the ternary operator work?

Comment: I do when I feel the answer has pin pointed my question. I often ask bad and ambiguous answers though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public int? userId 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        int rv; 
        return int.TryParse(userIdString, out rv) ? (int?)rv : null; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 for typing faster than I can! :P

Comment: But apparently, someone didn't like that answer --- I got down-voted (but it seems, he hit you too)

Comment: Yeah... I've just learned to ignore the down-vote trolls...

Comment: I downvoted both because I think other answers were better and would like them at the top, and that's what up/down-votes are for. @md5sum, just because you get a downvote it does not mean that the answer is bad. It's just a way to move answers up/down.

Comment: @Filip: But Anthony's is just wrong, and Bob's, while correct, merely repeats what the OP already knows, without helping him fix it.

Comment: @Filip, see it how you wish, but I tend to think downvotes should be reserved for answers that are wrong or while technically correct (meaing, it will work), ill-advised code. Mine *was* wrong, though. At least, in the diagnosis portion!

Comment: Just giving code rarely helps the OP, next time he will ask how to do similar things. Some explaining content is always much better than just a code-sample. And also @md5sum's answer is a duplicate and should be deleted therefore also downvoted.

Comment: Every time I start to get enthusiastic about SO and try to help people, someone like @Filip comes along and reminds me to not waste my time here, or at least not to believe the SO rep means anything in particular.

Comment: @Anthony: Actually, I was refering to your "(int?)null" part, which I *thought* was wrong. But after Jon Skeet recommended the same thing, I had to actually try it to prove to myself that it would work.

Comment: Well, yeah, you can cast either side, but now you've learned casting null to `int?` is valid. You just need to get away from  `bool ? int : null`, because the compiler will not automatically say "`int` can be `int?`, `null` can be `int?`, OK, this expression returns `int?`." It will make the leap for one of them when given appropriate info, but not for both.

Answer (score 4):

```
public int? userId
{
    get
    {
        int rv;
        return int.TryParse(userIdString, out rv) ? (int?)rv : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I hadn't read the question carefully enough; the problem isn't that the conditional operator doesn't like nulls - it's that it needs to know what the overall type of the expression should be... and that type has to be the type of *either* the left-hand side, *or* the right-hand side. `null` itself is a type-less expression which can be converted to many types; `int` is a perfectly valid type, but it's one of the types which `null` *can't* be converted to. You can either make the right-hand side explicitly of type `int?` and get the implicit conversion of `int` to `int?` from the left-hand side, *or* you can perform a cast on the left-hand side, and get the implicit conversion of `null` to `int?`.

My answer is like James's, but casting the null instead:

```
public int? userId 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        int rv; 
        return int.TryParse(userIdString, out rv) ? rv : (int?) null; 
    } 
}
```

This is to emphasize that it's *not* a null reference; it's a null value of type `int?`. At that point, the conversion of the int `rv` is obvious.

There are two other alternatives along the same lines to consider though:

```
return int.TryParse(userIdString, out rv) ? rv : new int?(); 

return int.TryParse(userIdString, out rv) ? rv : default(int?);
```

Personally I think the "casted null" is the nicest form, but you can make up your own mind.

Another alternative would be to have a generic static method:

```
public static class Null
{
    public static T? For<T>() where T : struct
    {
        return default(T?);
    }
}
```

and write:

```
return int.TryParse(userIdString, out rv) ? rv : Null.For<int>();
```

I don't think I really like that, but I offer it for your inspection :)

Comment: I like the in-depth approach here... question though: Is the casting of the null to `int?` for the compiler or for the developers?

Comment: @md5sum: Both... without it, the compiler won't know which type to use for the overall conditional expression.

Comment: @md5sum, when given `bool ? int : null`, the compiler will not leap to say *both* are convertible to `int?`. It will make the leap for one of them and say `int` can be `int?` or `null` can be `int?`, but you need to plant the `int?` suggestion in the compiler's brain, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a (non-nullable) int or null in the same expression. You'll need to explicitly return a `int?` in your ternary expression for that to work.