# Issue with setting a DateTime? to null using ternary operator

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type result with conditional operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815033/type-result-with-conditional-operator-in-c)

I was just working on an a pop-up for modifying a user, when I ran into the following issue while attempting to modify the user's Date of Death :

In this scenario, the property `Death` for the user is a `DateTime?` (Nullable Date Time).

```
user.Death = (model.Death != null) ? DateTime.Parse(model.Death) : null;
```

So I figured that I would be able to simply check if the value contained in the model (model.Death is a `string`) contained a value, I would set the date that value, otherwise I would set it to null, as demonstrated above.

However, I was unable to use this syntax, as it would not allow me to explicitly set `user.Death` to null, using the ternary operator, although `user.Death = null` worked just fine.

**Solution used :**

Replaced `: null` with `: new Nullable<DateTime>()`

**I guess I am just wondering, why was I unable to explicitly set a Nullable DateTime property to null using a ternary operator?**

Comment: common question, check the above link. Short version: DateTime and null are not convertible to one another, so the return type of the expression cannot be determined. Casting one or both to the desired return type is what you need to do, or (as you found) provide another type in the expression that allows one to be convertible to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work because the compiler will not insert an implicit conversion on both sides at once.

You want the compiler to convert a `DateTime` value to `DateTime?` on one side, and `null` to `DateTime?` on the other side.
This cannot happen.

If you explicitly convert either half to `DateTime?`, the other half will implicitly convert too.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if user.Death=null would have worked if the Death is not declared as nullable type.

For eg. "DateTime? death=null" would work fine whereas "DateTime death=null" would not compile.