# When using the ternary conditional operator, why does the compiler care if TypeA is convertable to TypeB and vice versa?

Tags: c#, .net, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type result with conditional operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815033/type-result-with-conditional-operator-in-c)

Basically I have some code like this:

```
IEnumerable<Effect> effects = ( ( activeOnly ) ? this.ActiveEffects : this.AllEffects ).Select ( e => e );
```

where:

```
this.ActiveEffects is:
class ActiveEffectList : IEnumerable<Effect>

this.AllEffects is:
class EffectList : IEnumerable<Effect>
```

which is why I expected the above statement to work, but it returns this compile error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot
>   be determined because there is no
>   implicit conversion between
>   'ImageEditor.ActiveEffectList' and
>   'ImageEditor.EffectList'

Comment: this is a common question, check the above duplicate. Short short version is type must be able to be determined from the expression on the right, the type on the left is not part of that logic.

Comment: I answered this by linking to another similar question, but Anthony's got it right - the proposed duplicate answers this handily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by casting the first value to `IEnumerable<Effect>`:

```
var effects = activeOnly ?
              (IEnumerable<Effect>) this.ActiveEffects :
              this.AllEffects;
```

The problem is that even though you're assigning to IEnumerable, the compiler needs to evaluate the conditional expression **before** the cast happens and since the conditional statement needs both paths to return the same type, you are getting an error that `AllEffects` can't be cast to `ActiveEffects`.

By casting the first value in the statement to IE`numerable<Effect>`, you are forcing the conditional statement to return `IEnumerable<Effect>` rather than one of the more specific types.

Comment: Thanks but why cast only the first one? I would think you need need to cast both? What's the difference?

Comment: @Joan, you can cast either. The idea is that at least one must be convertible to the other, you can generally cast either side. It will evaluate if X can go to Y or if Y can go to X.

Comment: @Joan - By casting the first, you are setting the type for the expression. .NET will automatically try to convert the second value to the type of the expression...so it will handle that second cast for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Because it does not look at base types or the left side type when resolving the types.**

You solve this by changing your statement into:

```
IEnumerable<Effect> effects = ( ( activeOnly ) ? (IEnumerable<Effect>)this.ActiveEffects : this.AllEffects ).Select ( e => e );
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a ternary expression is an expression, and expressions have a type. The compiler doesn't try to find the closest common assignment-compatible type (as such a search could potentially be *very* complicated and would usually be of little value). In your case, you have two *completely different types*. All types (outside of unsafe blocks, in general) have a common ancestor at `object`, but the compiler doesn't look up the chain; if the two types don't have assignment compatibility in at least one direction, then you have to tell it what you want.

The easy solution is to cast one of the operands to the desired type. This will direct the compiler to compare the other operand to that type, which it will immediately see as compatible. So, in other words, cast one operand to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes have both inherited from the same base (IEnumerable), but could have different implementations.  Before the assignment operator, the ternary operator first has to return a common type between the two values, and cannot convert b to a.

According to the reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Either do this:

```
IEnumerable<Effect> effects = ( ( activeOnly ) ? (IEnumerable<Effect>)this.ActiveEffects : this.AllEffects ).Select ( e => e );
```

Or add a implicit conversion operator to your classes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(VS.71).aspx