# I'm doing some coding interview practice questions and I don't know why the answer to this problem is 65, 65

Tags: c#, ternary

```
public class Program
    {      
      public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          char x = 'A';
           int i = 0;
          Console.WriteLine (true  ? x : 0);
          Console.WriteLine(false ? i : x); 
        }
    }
```

I can't find anything on google, someone please shed some light on why the output is 65,65

Comment: 65 is the ASCII code for 'A'.  Your ternary is evaluating to an integer.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can implicitly convert char to int but not the other way arround so the int type wins and sets the type of the result.

If it was the other way around you would get 'A' as the result.

Details https://stackoverflow.com/a/220268/11869962).

```
        int intVar = '1';       //ok
        char charVar = (char)1; //ok
        char charVarError = 1;  //error
```

Answer (score 2):

Because a `char` is nothing but a number, more precisely a signed `int`, as seen on the docs:

> The char type is implicitly convertible to the following integral
>   types: ushort, int, uint, long, and ulong

The character `'A'` has the unicode-codepoint `65`. Thus your ternary just returns `int`, in your case `65`.

See more about `char` on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char

Answer (score 2):

A is 65 in ASCII encoding. The ternary operator is is essentially outputting the char value of A, in this case 65.

The ternary operator is essentially an `if else` statement. So `Console.WriteLine (true  ? x : 0);` will output 65 as x is in the true portion of the ternary. `Console.WriteLine(false ? i : x);` will also output 65 as x is in the false (else) portion of the ternary