# How to Handle Non-Required File Upload Fields in DALC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I'm coding an Admin form. The user may or may not update PDF file(s); if he does I'm handling it in my form coded as follows:

```
string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(regFormUpload.FileName);
if (regFormUpload.HasFile)
{
    if (string.Equals(fileExt, ".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Stream pdfFileStream = regFormUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
        fileData = new byte[regFormUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength];
        pdfFileStream.Read(fileData, 0, regFormUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength);

        // Call DALC method with uploaded file(s) params
    }
    else
    {
        regFormCustVal.IsValid = false;
    }
}
else
{
    // Call DALC method indicating "null" for non-uploaded files(s)???
}
```

Is there a way to pass a null to the DALC/Stored Procedure? It's being stored in SQL Server as a varbinary(max) type. Previously I used to code separate methods depending on whether or not someone uploaded a file and I know there has to be an easier way but the C# syntax is escaping me.

**UPDATE - 05-24-2012**

I still haven't got an answer to this. In my DALC, I currently have to call several DB update methods, depending on whether files (byte[]) has been uploaded or not. Is there anyway to get around this? I have two separate file upload controls and both are non-required fields. This means I have to code up to four separate DB update methods to account for the (2^2) possibilities!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "nullable byte array" ?

Comment: What if the extension is ".PDF"?

Comment: Good point, thanks :) Updated question.

Comment: What if the extension is *.PdF"?

Comment: @usr, question re-opened and code updated :)

Comment: What if the extension is ".pdf2"? :) (Use string.Equals(fileExt, ".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Comment: You probably already know this...for a stored proc to accept null I would declare the variable as @myvar varbinary(max) =null.   In C# declare the variable as string? myvar;

Comment: In the C# code-behind, it's a byte[] array (PDF file)

Comment: I put 50 points bounty on this and it becomes community wiki????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to this was to code four overrides for the DB Add method - which was what I was trying to avoid in the first place. Received no response showing a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a Nullable Byte Array, you can always set an Array to null.

As for the file upload, you might do it like the documentation for [FileUpload.PostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx) suggests in the example.

UPDATE: Not sure how your DALC works but for passing the array to an stored procedure just make sure to pass `DBNull.Value` when the array is null.

UPDATE 2: You have to pass `DBNull.Value` to the procedure, for the DAL just set the array to null.

```
fileData = null;
```

Then when you call the procedure you have to check the property and either pass the value or `DBNull.Value`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555935/how-to-assign-null-to-a-sqlparameter) on how to do that.

Comment: You say "nullable array of bytes", I say "array of nullable bytes".

Comment: Gives Error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'byte[]'

Comment: Had to uncheck this as answer - does not answer how to handle the fact that an array of bytes cannot be null. Updating question.