# Passing Empty Sql Parameter Give Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am passing array of SQL Parameters to my wrapper function like

```
  SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] { 
            new SqlParameter("@UserName",userName),
            new SqlParameter("@Password",password)
  };
```

When i pass null value to parameter sql server gives me error that :

Procedure or function 'AuthenticateUser' expects parameter '@Password', which was not supplied.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555935/how-to-assign-null-to-a-sqlparameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass dbnull value then the parameter value is null:

```
SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] { 
            new SqlParameter("@UserName",(object)userName ?? DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("@Password",(object)password ?? DBNull.Value)
  };
```

Comment: Thanks alex but i get other error that is ?? can not be applied to string  and system.DBNull

Comment: cast parametrs to object first: (object)userName ?? DBNull.Value