# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime, stored procedure empty parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, is-empty

I wrote a stored procedure in SQL Server. I have a parameter of type `smalldatetime`. I want to send this parameter blank when I run it with LINQ. When I want to send it, I get this error.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How can I send the date format blank?

C#, LINQ;

```
  var query = ctx.onayListele(Convert.ToDateTime(dataList.olusturulmaTarihi)).ToList();
```

SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[onayListele]
    @in_olusturmaTarihi smalldatetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Onay.onayID, alep.olusturulmaTarihi, TalepTuru.talepTuruAdi, 
        TalepDurumu.talepDurumuAciklamasi 
    FROM 
        Onay 
    WHERE
        (@var_olusturmaTarihi IS NULL OR 
         CONVERT(DATE, Talep.olusturulmaTarihi) = CONVERT(DATE, @var_olusturmaTarihi))
END
```

Comment: If you were to simply run "DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dataList.olusturulmaTarihi);" does this produce the same error? If so you need to figure out why that value is not seen as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Because dataList.collection is sent as dataList.olusturulmaTarihi = "". And I do not know how to send the datetime parameter blank?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Stored Procedure with a null parameter value with EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373595/call-stored-procedure-with-a-null-parameter-value-with-entityframework)

Comment: All you need to do is change the `@in_olusturmaTarihi` data type to `Date` and remove the conversion of it in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I thought you needed to change your stored procedure.
Now that I've read the question again, I've realized that the error message comes from the c# side, not from the stored procedure (that I still think you should change).

Attempting to convert a null or empty string to `DateTime` will result with the error in your question. To avoid that, you need to make sure the string can in fact be converted to `DateTime` before sending it to the stored procedure:

```
DateTime datetime;
DateTime? olusturulmaTarihi = null;
if(DateTime.TryParse(dataList.olusturulmaTarihi, out datetime))
{
    olusturulmaTarihi = (DateTime?)datetime;
}
var query = ctx.onayListele(olusturulmaTarihi).ToList();
```

This way, you will send `null` to the stored procedure if the string can't be parsed as `DateTime`, and avoid the error.

As to the stored procedure, I would suggest writing it like this instead:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[onayListele]
    @in_olusturmaTarihi date = NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT  Onay.onayID, 
           alep.olusturulmaTarihi, 
           TalepTuru.talepTuruAdi, 
           TalepDurumu.talepDurumuAciklamasi 
   FROM Onay 
   WHERE @var_olusturmaTarihi IS NULL 
   OR CONVERT(date,Talep.olusturulmaTarihi) = @var_olusturmaTarihi
END
```

Please note that if you have an index on `Talep.olusturulmaTarihi`, this stored procedure will not be able to use it. In that case, you better use something like this instead:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[onayListele]
    @in_olusturmaTarihi date = NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT  Onay.onayID, 
           alep.olusturulmaTarihi, 
           TalepTuru.talepTuruAdi, 
           TalepDurumu.talepDurumuAciklamasi 
   FROM Onay 
   WHERE @var_olusturmaTarihi IS NULL 
   OR 
   (
       Talep.olusturulmaTarihi >= CAST(@var_olusturmaTarihi as datetime) -- or whatever the data type of the column is
       AND Talep.olusturulmaTarihi < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(@var_olusturmaTarihi as datetime)) -- or whatever the data type of the column is
   )
END
```