# SqlCommand parameters, shorter way of adding nullable value?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Writing data layer code against T-SQL, I often have to add a `SqlParameter` to a `SqlCommand`. In the case of a nullable type (for example a `DateTime?`), I write it like this:

```
if (t.StartDate.HasValue)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@start_date", t.StartDate));
else
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@start_date", DBNull.Value));
```

I can't use the ternary operator `?:`, as the IntelliSense/compiler will complain that "there is no implicit conversion between type 'System.DateTime?' and 'System.DBNull'.

Is there a shorter/neater way of writing my 4 lines of code?

Comment: You can always use the cast operator to tell the compiler which common type you want to use, in this case `System.Object`.

Comment: Just encapsulate this into an extension method, then reuse it everywhere you need it.

Comment: If you need a shorter way you can always use an extension like the one if've just written here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39446645/284240

Answer (score -1):

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@start_date", t.StartDate.HasValue?t.StartDate:DBNull.Value));
```

Comment: That won't compile (as OP already stated in the question) as long as you don't cast at least one of the two results of the ternary operator to something like `object`.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".