# Sql how to change query based on parameters

Tags: sql, date, if-statement, case

Sorry I don't know how to put it in title, I have this query on an aspx page with 2 datepickers (let's say data and data2)

```
select utenti.nome as tecnico, Richieste.IDRic as idchia, richieste.descr as rdescr, ISNULL(richieste.assistremota,0) as assremota, Clienti.RagSociale as ragsoc, richieste.descr as descr, richieste.priorita as prior, richieste.tipo as tipo, richieste.rforologio as rforo, ISNULL(statoric.appuntamento,0) as app, ISNULL(statoric.oradalle,0) as dalle, ISNULL(statoric.oraalle,0) as alle, statoric.ID as idstato 
from clienti 
inner join richieste on clienti.idcliente = richieste.rfcliente 
inner join statoric on statoric.rfric = richieste.idric 
inner join stati on stati.idstato = statoric.rfstato 
inner join utenti on utenti.idutente=statoric.rftecnico 
where statoric.attuale = 1 and statoric.rfstato < 14 and statoric.dataass = @data and statoric.rftecnico = 8 order by app desc, oraalle asc, prior desc
```

I need to change the "statoric.dataass = @data" part to do this (pseudocode):

```
if data 2 is null then 
    "statoric.dataass = @data"
else
    "statoric.dataass between @data and @data2"
end if
```

How can I do it? I tried case and If but I'm doing something wrong... thanks

Comment: also note between can cause problems if you do use TIME part

Comment: this doesn't work, it also returns records before data2

Comment: BETWEEN is equivalent to data1<= datass<= data2 so i swaped the dates: data1 <= datass AND (data2 is null OR datass <= data2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try coalesce

```
... statoric.dataass between @data and coalesce(@data2, @data) ...
```

Comment: So simple, thanks! I just improved it a bit like this statoric.dataass between @data and coalesce(NULLIF(@data2,''), @data) because I can have both null or empty values

Comment: I have a problem using this on ASP.NET, seems like it is interpreting it differently from sql server. If I execute the query with statoric.dataass between data and coalesce(NULLIF(data2,''), data) on sql server I get the right result even if data2=null, instead on asp.net it returns nothing (but then it works if I select data2). Any hint?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555935/assign-null-to-a-sqlparameter for example

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
where statoric.attuale = 1 and
      statoric.rfstato < 14 and
      ( (@data2 is null and statoric.dataass = @data) or
         statoric.dataass between @data and @data2
      ) and
      statoric.rftecnico = 8
```

However, you might consider this:

```
where statoric.attuale = 1 and
      statoric.rfstato < 14 and
      statoric.dataass >= @data and
      statoric.dataass <= coalesce(@data2, @data) and
      statoric.rftecnico = 8
```

The advantage of this approach is that it can take advantage of an index on `(attuale, rftecnico, dataass)`.

Comment: I have a problem using this on ASP.NET, seems like it is interpreting it differently from sql server. If I execute the query with data2=null on sql server I get the right result, instead on asp.net it returns nothing (but then it works if I select data2). Any hint?

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino . . . I don't understand why that would be an issue.  Could `@data` be `NULL`?  Your question doesn't suggest that could be the case.

Comment: There are 2 datepickers on the page, the query is triggered by date change of each, so if user select data2 first then data can be null and vice versa