# The this keyword and double question mark (??) confuse me

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c)

Is this a new feature added to C# 3.x ?

e.g

```
public class HttpRequests
{
    public string GetHtmlContent(this HttpRequest myRequest)
    {            
       //do something
       return retStr ?? (retStr=new GetHtmlStr(urlStr));
    }
}
```

The **this** and **??** are strange to me since I have not updated my know of C# for years. I know C# 2.x.

For conditional **if** and return value i.e

`return a == 0 ? a:b;`

yes I can understand what this is.
Could someone please explain ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: three question in one post

Comment: The code you've given invalid. Extension methods (the `this` part) have to be on static methods, in static classes. And of course you haven't declared `retStr` anywhere.

Comment: Also: [What are extension methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods), [What do two question marks together mean in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c) and [Question mark and colon mean in statement? what does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957214/question-mark-and-colon-mean-in-statement-what-does-it-mean).

Answer (score 3):

`??` - [**null coalescing operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) introduced with .Net 2.0

`this` in method -> specifies [**extension method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) on existing type, introduced with C# 3.0

Answer (score 1):

**this** refers to Extension method

Regarding Extension method you can find a comprehensive detail at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

---

> The **??** operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for a nullable value types as well as reference
>   types. It returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise
>   it returns the right operand.

Comment: Sorry, but the last part is entirely wrong. You're doing a comparison.  You probably meant to assign a value, but that would be also wrong, coalesce does not assign any value. So "a ?? b" would be correctly translated to "a != null ? a : b", and "a ?? b ?? c" to "a != null ? a : (b != null ? b : c))".

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow - thnx edited!.

Answer (score 0):

This is a null-coalising operator, see [MSDN explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
GetHtmlContent(this HttpRequest myRequest)
```

Well this infers it to be an `Extension method` but does your code compile since your class is **not static**

> When the first parameter of a method includes the this modifier, that
>   method is said to be an extension method. Extension methods can only
>   be declared in non-generic, non-nested static classes. The first
>   parameter of an extension method can have no modifiers other than
>   this, and the parameter type cannot be a pointer type.

Also `??` is a null coalescing operator

```
string something = maybenull ?? "I cannot be null";
```

so when `maybenull` object is null you get the other string assigned to your string.

Answer (score 0):

### This Qualifier

When using `this` qualifier before the first parameter in a static method inside a static class, the method is called "extension method". Basically you are saying to the compiler: "hey, I'd like to add this method to an existing class without modifying it".

LINQ makes use of them intensively (see [Enumerable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) for more details).

### ?? or Null-Coalescing Operator

?? or Null-Coalescing Operator is a syntactic sugar for:

```
var2 = var1 == null ? something : var1;
```

You can, in facts, replace the above operation with a simple line of code:

```
var2 = var1 ?? something;
```

Comment: Sorry, but your part about the coalescing operator is wrong. The coalesce operator does NOT assign a value! So "var2 = something" is WRONG. "a ?? b" would be correctly translated to "a != null ? a : b", and "a ?? b ?? c" to "a != null ? a : (b != null ? b : c))".

Comment: @AS-CII It’s still wrong because when `var1` is not null, `var1` will be assigned to `var2`. And that is not the case in your first code example.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's new features.

**this** before the first method parameter means that the method is a extension method. I'm pretty sure the function needs to be static to be valid.

So to use that method, you could write

```
HttpRequest request;
// assign request
request.GetHtmlContent();
```

And it would call GetHtmlContent with request as the parameter.

The ?? is the null-coalescing operator, and is used to simplify a check for null.

Instead of

```
string s;
// ... s something something
// return s == null ? s = "default" : s;
```

which means that if the string s is null, return this value instead, but if it's not null, return the value of s, you can simply write:

return s ?? "default";

Which returns s if it's not null, and default if s is null.