# What is meant by this code line? (Code Hunt)

Tags: c#, loops

I tried to solve Level 03.03 in Code Hunt. But, as I found no solution, I got this code line from the internet.

```
public static int Puzzle(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    return lowerBound == upperBound ? upperBound : (upperBound * Puzzle(lowerBound,upperBound - 1));
}
```

The solutions are:

```
lowerBound      upperBound      EXPECTED RESULT
1               8               40320
15              24              244963328
16              17              272
```

Does anyone has an idea for, what is meant with this code? I just don't get it.

Comment: It's a `conditional operator`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957214/question-mark-and-colon-mean-in-statement-what-does-it-mean

Comment: What part of the code is it that you don't understand? Is it the conditional operator or is it the use of recursion?

Comment: Please Please Please, One search before asking question

Comment: You're right, but I haven't found anything. @jpw Thanks for the answers, it was the conditional operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(lowerBound == upperBound)
{
     return upperBound;
}
else
{
    return (upperBound * Puzzle(lowerBound,upperBound - 1));
}
```

You can read about condition operator here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx