# Why we use '?' character in c#

Tags: c#

I am looking at somebody code. I found:

```
XOffset = !MirroredMovement ? trans.x * MoveRate : -trans.x * MoveRate;
```

He use '?' character, why ? What does it mean ? I did not understand.

Comment: Just go to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: ternary operator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: Explanation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957214/question-mark-and-colon-mean-in-statement-what-does-it-mean

Comment: https://github.com/ranguera/Kinect-DAT/blob/master/KinectScripts/AvatarController.cs

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano what does this link describes? It seams that a code page from a project

Comment: Is the source code of this question and it has a lots of /* comments */ , this is because i link it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` is not the operator, the combination of `?` and `:` is the operator, called 'ternary operator'.

The ternary operator is an operator that takes three arguments. The first argument is a comparison argument, the second is the result upon a true comparison, and the third is the result upon a false comparison. If it helps you can think of the operator as shortened way of writing an if-else statement.

Answer (score 2):

That's the Ternary Operator.

```
condition ? value1 : value2
```

Its short for:

```
if (condition)
{
    return value1;
}
else
{
    return value2;
}
```

In this example you could write this:

```
XOffset = !MirroredMovement ? trans.x * MoveRate : -trans.x * MoveRate;
```

like that:

```
if (!MirroredMovement)
{
    XOffset = trans.x * MoveRate;
}
else
{
    XOffset = -trans.x * MoveRate;
}
```