# Please Explain this C# LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I found this piece of code on **stackoverflow** some time ago, but can't seem to find it again. All credit to the author. Sorry I could not link.

**QUESTION?** Can some C# LINQ guru please break down this statement step by step as I am having difficulty understanding it. It certainly works well and does the job, but how?

Line to Split

```
var line = $"13351.750815 26646.150876 6208.767863 26646.150876 1219.200000 914.400000 0.000000 1 \"Beam 1\" 0 1 1 1 0 1 1e8f59dd-142d-4a4d-81ff-f60f93f674b3";
var splitLineResult = line.Trim().Split('"')
                                    .Select((element, index) => index % 2 == 0
                                    ? element.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                    : new string[] { element })
                                    .SelectMany(element => element).ToList();
```

**Result of Statement in LinqPad**
[image]

Comment: Honestly, people have explained what the code does but it does NOT need to do all that gymnastics. The goal is to get all the items out of one long string. I would simply do this: 1) Split the whole thing using quotes 2) Split the first part using a space 3) Split the last part using a space 4) Concatenate the results. Simple! [Check it Out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Enc3nF).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to begin by analysing the input you have in hand.

```
13351.750815 26646.150876 6208.767863 26646.150876 1219.200000 914.400000 0.000000 1 "Beam 1" 0 1 1 1 0 1 1e8f59dd-142d-4a4d-81ff-f60f93f674b3
```

The input consists of few alphanumeric strings separated by **Whitespace**. However, there is one special case that needs to be handled as well. The word "`Beam 1`" is enclosed in **Quotes**.

Now, let's break down the Linq statement.

```
 line.Trim().Split('"')
```

The first statement splits the input based on the delimiter **Quotes**. This splits the string into 3 parts.

[image]

As you can observe the first(**in 0th Index**) and Last(**in index position 2**) needs to be split further while, the element in the in index position 1 has already been parsed. This is where the second part of Linq statement comes into picture.

```
.Select((element, index) => index % 2 == 0
                                    ? element.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                    : new string[] { element })
```

In the above statement the `Select((element, index) => index % 2 == 0` part checks if the current index position is in an even position. If so, it needs to be split the substring further based on delimiter `' ' (whitespace)`. Otherwise, it creates an array with single entity 'Beam 1'

At the end of the second part, what you get is a collection 3 sub-collections of alphanumeric strings (`IEnumerble<string[]>`).

[image]

What now needs to be done is create a collection by flattening the parent collection. This done using [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8).

```
.SelectMany(element => element).ToList();
```

[image]

Hope that helped in understanding the Linq query better

Comment: `What now needs to be done is create a collection by **joining** these collection`, not joining, **flattening**.

Comment: The _parent_ collection is flattened, but the children are effectively concatenated.

Answer (score 2):

Breaking up the statement

```
    var splitLineResult = line.Trim().Split('"')
                            .Select((element, index) => index % 2 == 0
                            ? element.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            : new string[] { element }).ToList()
                            .SelectMany(element => element).ToList();
```

1. `Trim()`: [Removes any spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim) in the beginning or the end.
2. `Split('"')`: [Split the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) into an array of string with double quote as a delimiter
3. `Select()`: [Only select a specific part from the element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) being iterated. In this scenario, its the element and its index in the entire string (starts with 0).
4. Within your select statement, you have `%2 ==0` .. which is true only for every other element. (skips 1)
5. [You can do an if else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957233/1390548) with `?` and `:`

   a. `If true print 1 else print 0` can be thought of as `true ? print 1 : print 0`
6. `SelectMany()`: [Selects all the elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) that are returned. Instead of returning 3 arrays, it returns the elements from each of the array.
7. `ToList()`: [Converts the array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8) to a list.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there are some really good answers here already, but I had already almost finished mine when I saw people had beat me to it, so here's my version. Hope it brings something to the table.
My approach was writing it out in non Linq code with comments

```
var line = $"13351.750815 26646.150876 6208.767863 26646.150876 1219.200000 914.400000 0.000000 1 \"Beam 1\" 0 1 1 1 0 1 1e8f59dd-142d-4a4d-81ff-f60f93f674b3";
line = line.Trim(); //remove leading and trailing white space
var tempArray1 = line.Split('"'); //split the line to a string array on "
                                  //so the string array we get, is everything before, between, and after "

//.Select((element, index)
//Basically doing a for-loop on the array we got
List<string[]> tempListForElements = new List<string[]>(); //initialize a temporary list of string arrays we're going to be using
for (var index = 0; index < tempArray1.Length; index++)
{
    var element = tempArray1[index];

    //now we're getting to the ternary, which is basically like an inline if-else statement
    //index % 2 == 0 ? <if true> : <if false>
    //if remainder of division by 2 is 0, so basically a way of doing two 
    //different things for every other iterator of the loop
    if (index % 2 == 0)
    {
        //if on the first or last iteraton on the loop (before and after " in the line)
        tempListForElements.Add(element.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));  //we create yet another string array splitting on each whitespace and add it to our temporary list
    }
    else
    {
        //if on the second iteraton on the loop (between ")
        tempListForElements.Add(new string[] { element }); //we're creating yet another string array, this time there's just one element in the array though, and then add it to our temporary list
    }
}

//.SelectMany(element => element).ToList()
//we're basically turning out list of 3 string array into one string array
//can't be asked to type it out in non linq since just realized there are some good answers here already,
//but imagine initializing a string array with the correct size and then a foreach loop adding each string to it in order.
```

Answer (score 1):

if you convert this Linq in normal for loop it will look like this.

```
var line = $"13351.750815 26646.150876 6208.767863 26646.150876 1219.200000 914.400000 0.000000 1 \"Beam 1\" 0 1 1 1 0 1 1e8f59dd-142d-4a4d-81ff-f60f93f674b3";
    string[] splitLineResult = line.Trim().Split('"');
    var list = new List<string[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitLineResult.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
        {
            list.Add(splitLineResult[i].Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        }
        else 
        {
            list.Add(new string[] { splitLineResult[i] });
        }
    }
    var finalList = list.SelectMany(x=>x).ToList();
```

and for SelectMany method, you can refer MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8