# What type can I expect from a ternary operation?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this code invalid in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202271/why-is-this-code-invalid-in-c)
>   [Conditional operator cannot cast implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215745/conditional-operator-cannot-cast-implicitly)

If I do the following:

```
bool someBool = false;
uint value = 0;
```

These are fine:

```
value = (someBool) ? 0 : (uint)1;
value = (someBool) ? (uint)0 : 1;
```

But this is not:

```
value = (someBool) ? 0 : 1;
```

Why can I not use the last one when I can easily say:

```
value = 0;
value = 1;
```

How is the type of the ternary operator determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My short summary :

```
  var x = c ? a : b;
```

The compiler will try if `b` is convertible to the type of `a`, otherwise if `a` is convertible to the type of `b`.  When neither is possible there is an error.

But in

```
 uint value = (someBool) ? 0 : 1;
```

the ternary operator simply return `int` (both `a` and `b` are ints here).

The variable on the left side of the assignment is **not** considered when determining the type.

Answer (score 4):

You must cast it to `uint` so the compiler will know.  Both 0 and 1 could be a `uint` or an `int`.

Here is the language specification (which can be downloaded from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)):

> The second and third operands of the ?: operator control the type of
>   the conditional expression. Let X and Y be the types of the second and
>   third operands. Then,
>
> If X and Y are the same type, then this is the type of the conditional
>   expression.
>
> Otherwise, if an implicit conversion exists from X to Y,
>   but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> Otherwise, if an implicit conversion exists from Y to X, but not from
>   X to Y, then X is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Can't get better than the language spec :)

Comment: Thanks, can you post the link where you found that? I checked msdn and didn't find this.

Comment: @NominSim: Provided a link for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not cast any of the numbers to `uint`, the compiler is going to assume that the result of the ternary operator is an `int`, which cannot be implicitly converted to `uint`.