# Syntax error when using if-statement to a DateTime? variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm getting a syntax error when attempting to compile this code, and I'm not quite sure why. Could anyone help me with fixing this code?

```
DateTime? ModifiedDate = null;

ModifiedDate = (dbReader["ModifiedDate"] == DBNull.Value ? null : DateTime.Parse(dbReader['ModifiedDate'].ToString()));
```

Comment: What **is** the syntax error? I think I could figure it out, but it's better if you post it.

Comment: Note that there is no "if" statement involved. If you used an if/else to perform the assignments, the compiler would not have complained. Note also that this is a common question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202271/why-is-this-code-invalid-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to the conditional operator, both sides of the condition should return the *same* type (or types that are implicitly convertible to each other).

Now `null` is not a specific type, which is part of the problem - you need to cast it to `DateTime?` so it will match the other side - which has another issue: you are using `'` instead of `"`.

The following will work:

```
DateTime? ModifiedDate = 
               dbReader["ModifiedDate"] == DBNull.Value ? 
                          (DateTime?)null : 
                          DateTime.Parse(dbReader["ModifiedDate"].ToString());
```

Comment: FWIW - you could also cast the DateTime.Parse half to (DateTime?) and get the same result.

Comment: @MarkBrackett - true, though I like the cast of `null` better for explicitness and readability (I think it is less surprising than a cast of `DateTime` to `DateTime?`).

Comment: The ' was a typo when I created this posting cuz of seperate network.  I will give this a try.  A customer just called w/ a problem so i gonna run off for an hour.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime? ModifiedDate = dbReader["ModifiedDate"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(dbReader["ModifiedDate"].ToString());
```

You accidentally used the character separator instead of the string separator.  It's fixed above.

Comment: No, it isn't. Still will not compile.

Comment: So there's something else... I'll see.

Comment: @Oded I'm not quite sure where...

Comment: Something _additional_.

Comment: Oh right, saw your answer now. +1.