# VB.NET equivalent of C# "As"

Tags: .net, vb.net

What is the equivalent in VB.NET of the C# **As** keyword, as in the following?

```
var x = y as String;
if (x == null) ...
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It is [TryCast:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/trycast-operator)

```
Dim x As String = TryCast(y, String)
If x Is Nothing Then ...
```

Comment: +1 Although I believe `TryCast` is not **exactly** equivalent to `as` because `TryCast` doesn't work for value types?

Comment: @Mark: The *as* operator doesn't work on value types in C# either.

Comment: Well it works for nullable value types...  You can do: var x = y as int?; if (x == null) ... so you should be able to do Dim x = TryCast(y, System.Nullable(Of Integer)) in VB

Comment: @JoelFan, @nobugz. Oops. Let's try again. I believe `as` can convert value types into **nullable** types but `TryCast` can't? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746767/how-to-acheive-the-c-as-keyword-for-value-types-in-vb-net/746914#746914

Comment: This only works in very select cases because C# automatically applies a boxing conversion to "y".  It cannot convert, say, a double to an int?

Comment: @HansPassant C# will hardly ever "implicity" convert one primitive type (or any type) to another, you use the Convert.ToXXX method

Answer (score 9):

Trycast is what you're looking for.

```
Dim x = TryCast(y, String)
```

Answer (score 6):

TryCast:

```
Dim x = TryCast(y, String)
if (x Is Nothing) ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

C# code:

```
var x = y as String;
if (x == null) ...
```

VB.NET equivalent:

```
Dim x = TryCast(y, String)
If (x Is Nothing) ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Dim x = TryCast(y, [String])

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim x = TryCast(y, [String])
```

From: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with `?`:

```
TryCast(item, String)?.Substring(10)
```

It allows you to manage nullable without `if` :)

Comment: It seems question is not about  Ternary operator..Elaborate your answer