# Translate C# code to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I previously worked on a C# project but now I'm working with Visual Basic and what I want to do is simply translate the C# code to Visual Basic and it's going fine except for one piece of code of C# that I have no idea how to translate to VB

The C# code is:

```
private void ReadInput(Animal animal)
{
    // Mammal is a class that inherits from the Animal class
    Mammal mammal = animal as Mammal; //<<----How to translate this code?
    if (mammal != null)
    {
        mammal.Teeth = ReadTeeth();
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure how to translate `animal as Mammal` to Visual Basic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450185/vb-net-equivalent-of-c-sharp-as

Answer (score 3):

Use TryCast to treat animal as mammal

```
 Dim mammal As Mammal = TryCast(animal, Mammal)
```

Comment: @John.P, if it worked  then you should click the check mark.  Also note that in cases where `TryCast` fails, mammal will be `Nothing`, so you should check.

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece in your conversion is `TryCast(animal, Mammal)`

---

There are a lot of code converters online that can help you to answer questions of the type *"how can I translate code x from language y to language z?"*:

- [Telrik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)
- [developerFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)
- [DOTNET Spider](http://www.dotnetspider.com/convert/Csharp-To-Vb.aspx)
- [SharpDevelop](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx)

and more ...

Note: Some converters only work properly if you embed your code snippet into a class. For your specific example, some of them had trouble with the code comments. After removing them, everything went smooth.

They will yield something like this (comments removed):

```vb
Private Sub ReadInput(animal As Animal)
    Dim mammal As Mammal = TryCast(animal, Mammal)
    If mammal IsNot Nothing Then
        mammal.Teeth = ReadTeeth()
    End If
End Sub
```