# Is there a better way to do this: Convert.IsDBNull(row[somecolumn]) checking

Tags: c#, ado.net

Is there a better way to write this code..

```
MyObject pymt = new MyObject();
pymt.xcol1id= Convert.IsDBNull(row["col1id"]) ? 0 : (int)row["col1id"];
pymt.xcold2id= Convert.IsDBNull(row["col2id"]) ? String.Empty : (string)row["col2id"];
pymt.xcold3id = Convert.IsDBNull(row["CustNum"]) ? 0 : (decimal)row["xcold3id"];
```

could this be done in a cleaner way .. like generic methods etc??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to check for DBNull and then assign to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221582/most-efficient-way-to-check-for-dbnull-and-then-assign-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 11):

You could make generic extension methods like this:

```
public static class DataRowExtensions {

   public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this DataRow row, string key) {
      return row.GetValueOrDefault(key, default(T));
   }

   public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this DataRow row, string key, T defaultValue) {
      if (row.IsNull(key)) {
         return defaultValue;
      } else {
         return (T)row[key];
      }
   }

}
```

Usage:

```
MyObject pymt = new MyObject();
pymt.xcol1id = row.GetValueOrDefault<int>("col1id");
pymt.xcold2id = row.GetValueOrDefault<string>("col2id", String.Empty);
pymt.xcold3id = row.GetValueOrDefault<int>("CustNum"]);
```

Comment: +1 your implementation is better than mine, I address mine to fix what you mentioned. but now it looks dirty :(

Comment: I decided to use this approach because I am using VS2005, .net 2.0 version. Thank you all for your input, I very much appreciate it...

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely there's a cleaner way to write that code if you're using .NET 3.5, and without re-inventing extension methods that Microsoft already wrote for you. Just add a reference to [System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx), and you'll be able to do this:

```
MyObject pymt = new MyObject
                {
                    xcol1id = row.Field<int?>("col1id") ?? 0,
                    xcol2id = row.Field<string>("col2id") ?? String.Empty,
                    xcol3id = row.Field<decimal?>("col3id") ?? 0M
                };
```

Answer (score 7):

I tend to use the null coalescing operator in situations like those.  Also, DBNull.ToString returns string.Empty, so you don't have to do anything fancy there.

```
MyObject pymt = new MyObject();
pymt.xcol1id= row["col1id"] as int? ?? 0;
pymt.xcold2id= row["col2id"].ToString();
pymt.xcold3id = row["CustNum"] as decimal? ?? 0;
```

Comment: +1 I was going to write this initially, but decided to write a GenericConvert.

Comment: This won't work if the property you're setting is an int and not an int? will it?

Comment: it will, because the compiler realizes that there is no way that a null will be set.

Comment: While this works, I suspect the methods provided in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll are more efficient, as Reflector shows me a fair bit of code aimed at un-boxing value types efficiently in that assembly. To be fair, I haven't run any benchmarks to compare the two approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Better yet, add it as an extension method to the `DataRow`:

```
static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    if (!row.IsNull(columnName))
    {
        // Might want to support type conversion using Convert.ChangeType().
        return (T)row[columnName]
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

You can use it like:

```
pymt.xcol1id = row.GetValueOrDefault<int>("col1id");
pymt.xcol2id = row.GetValueOrDefault<string>("col2id");
pymt.xcol3id = row.GetValueOrDefault<decimal>("col3id");
```

Comment: Good point.  Your answer is more complete, better to up-vote your answer than to further add to the noise.

Answer (score 2):

```
 static ToType GenericConvert<ToType>(object value)
        {
            ToType convValue = default(ToType);

            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(value))
                convValue = (ToType)value;

            return convValue;
        }


MyObject pymt = new MyObject();
pymt.xcol1id= GenericConvert<int>(row["col1id"]);
pymt.xcold2id= GenericConvert<string>(row["col2id"]) ?? String.Empty;
pymt.xcold3id = GenericConvert<decimal>(row["CustNum"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually like that.  Our team had been using if/else statements which are more difficult to read in my opinion.

```
if (row["col1id"] == dbnull.value)
   pymt.xcol1id = 0;
else
   pymt.xcol1id = (int)row["col1id"];
```

Your code is easier to read because it places each assignment on individual lines.

A function as suggested by Stan might make the lines shorter but it hides the fact that nulls are being replaced unless you give it a very verbose name.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives I can quickly think of:

1. Strongly typed datasets
2. Use the SqlTypes readers like [ReadSqlInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlint32.aspx) since they all implement [INullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlint32.isnull.aspx).
3. Generate the code with XSLT transformation from XML, so the checking code is easy to change and maintain.