# IsDBNull vs DBNull.Value, are they the same?

Tags: .net, vb.net, evaluation, dbnull

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I'm not asking about (`Null` vs `DBNull.Value`) or (`IsDBNull` vs `IsNull`).

---

Well, I always use `IsDBNull()` to evaluate database fields and check if the value is `DBNull`, but I noticed that in many code examples, people use `DBNull.Value` for the same purpose. Here's how:

```vb
If IsDBNull(obj) Then DoSomething()      ' ---> My approach
If obj = DBNull.Value Then DoSomething() ' ---> Theirs.
```

Also in C#:

```c#
if (obj == DBNull.Value) {DoSomething();}
```

I did some search to find out if they're the same or if there's any difference between them, but can't find any useful articles that show *these two particular evaluation approaches* together.

[This MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx) demonstrates how `DBNull.Value.Equals` does the same thing as `IsDBNull` function, but never mentions/suggests using `DBNull.Value` for evaluation, without the use of `Equals` function.

So, I'm really wondering, is there any actual difference between these two so that one of them is recommended over the other? Or do they do the exact same thing?

Comment: That second line should use `Is` rather than `=` but, apart from that, they are functionally equivalent.  That `IsDBNull` method probably uses that second method internally.

Comment: [Here is the .Net implementation.](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs#L2917)

Comment: @WillRay, that is the implementation of the `SqlDataReader.IsDBNull` method, which is not the one specified in the question.  The method in the code above is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsDBNull`.

Comment: one reason why I don't use vb.net functions is because we will eventually have all code in c#. And if you use `Trim(str)` it is not translatable by converters. But if you use `str.Trim()` it will convert to c#. To answer your question, all you need to do is to download free disassembler and look at the function code. But you really shouldn't worry what `IsDbNull` does because you should use `DBNull.Value.Equals`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between null and System.DBNull.Value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958379/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-system-dbnull-value)

Comment: @jmcilhinney, how about the C# version? I've seen this many many times (Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12508016/4934172) for example).

Comment: @T.S. I already mentioned in my question that both `IsDBNull` and `DBNull.Value.Equals` do the same thing. Also some VB functions really come in handy and are more readable. Microsoft says in the MSDN link above: "*However, this method is rarely used because there are a number of other ways to evaluate a database field for missing data. These include the Visual Basic IsDBNull function...*". Side note: I don't use `Trim(str)` unless it's VB6 :D

Comment: @ChetanSanghani You don't even need to open the other question. Just by looking at their both titles, They're obviously talking about two different things :)

Comment: `if (obj == DBNull.Value) {DoSomething();}` in C# is exactly equivalent to `If obj Is DBNull.Value Then DoSomething()` in VB.

Comment: @jmcilhinney [apparently you're right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/814880/4934172). I didn't know that, and I guess that's what made the confusion. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

No, they are not the same. DBNull.Value is effectively a constant, while IsDBNull is a function that returns true or false.

The IsDbNull is a test flag returning Boolean and is a shortcut expression for use in **If Statements**. You can STILL use the Obj = DBNull.value method but **IsDbNull is the preferred method according the MS**.

However, if you want to use a select case statement, you still need to use the DBNull.value object

```
Select case Obj
    Case DBNull.value
    Case "Whatever"
End Select
```

Of course, you ALSO need DBNull.Value if you want to set a field back to a null value.

It is similar to Double.IsNaN and Double.NaN.

Comment: That's not what he is concerned.  He is asking whether the result of comparing obj isDBNull() is the same as obj == DBNull.value !!  The answer is YES, they are the same.