# Checking for null value (Empty Cell) in Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to count the number of empty cell in Excel sheet.

I read the double values for all Excel sheet but I can't count the null values since the code below does not work probably.

```
string path_connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + testbox_bath.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(path_connection);

OleDbDataAdapter adapter_STDsamverkan = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select [Kvalitetsklass (null)],[Std samverkan (null)]" + "from [Sheet1$]", connection);

DataTable dt_STDsamverkan = new DataTable();

adapter_STDsamverkan.Fill(dt_STDsamverkan);

for (int i = 0; i < dt_STDsamverkan.Rows.Count; i++)
{    
   if (dt_STDsamverkan.Rows[i].Field<double>(1) == null)
   {
        STDsamverkan_count2++;
   }
}
```

The hint on the IF statement is

> the result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type
>   'double' is never equal to 'null' of the type 'double?'

What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to check if a Data Table has a null value in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604414/best-way-to-check-if-a-data-table-has-a-null-value-in-it)

Comment: you almost certainly want to check for DBNull which is different than null; DBNull means there is no data for something; null means that something doesnt exist

Comment: Thanks @ryanyuyu and @Plutonix. I have tried to use `dt_STDsamverkan.Rows[i].Field<double>(1) == DBNull.Value`, but does not work. I got: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'double' is never equal to 'null' of type 'double?'

Comment: How can I work with the double values read from excel sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Double in reading Datatable. The double is nullable.

The answer for this question under the link below:

[double and null in c#](http://forums.asp.net/t/1116615.aspx?double%20and%20null%20in%20c%20)