# C#.NET MVC Razor View - can't compare DBNull value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Trying to determine whether a datetime value in datarow is null. i have no idea why this shouldn't work. i've also tried casting to string etc but keep getting same error:

> *Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.*

This error doesn't make sense to me, i'm not trying to cast it. I've tried many variants in trying to compare the datarow to DBNull, to no avail.

```
if(dataRows[0]["Reply_Deadline"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    if(Convert.ToDateTime(dataRows[0]["Reply_Deadline"]) <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        deadlinePast = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `Convert.IsDBNull(...)` method? Apparently calling `DBNull.Value` is pretty rare. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did, as per the example below, but i'm still getting the same error...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dataRows[0]["Reply_Deadline"]))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: here's another alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604414/best-way-to-check-if-a-data-table-has-a-null-value-in-it