# compare the value of Datetime with null or particular text in c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

I want to compare cell(Datetime) value to empty or "None".If it is not empty or none then after it will add the parameter.I would greatly appreciate of your help.

Thanks,It gives me can't convert date time to string error

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", row.Cell(2).GetValue<string>());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", row.Cell(3).GetValue<int>());
 if(row.Cell(4).GetValue<DateTime>() == "" || row.Cell(4).GetValue<DateTime>() =="none")
{
}
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expirydate", row.Cell(4).GetValue<DateTime>());
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Is this regarding a spreadsheet, like an excel file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4604459/3270427

Comment: Yeas,Jake I am reading data from Excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read it as a string first, check it, *then* convert it to a DateTime.

```
var s = row.Cell(4).GetValue<String>();
is (s != null && s != "" && s != "none")
{
    var d = DateTime.Parse(s);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expirydate", d);
}
```

Or rethink the problem.  Instead of relying on a [magic number](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-using-magic-numbers-and-string-literals-in-your-code/), just populate the expiration date whenever it is a valid date, like so:

```
var s = row.Cell(4).GetValue<String>();
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out d))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expirydate", d);
}
```

Since "none" and "" are not valid dates, this will work, and in addition it will continue to work if someone puts in "None", "N/A", "Never", etc.

Comment: Thank you man But I did with my way. `var expiry = row.Cell(4).GetValue<string>();                            
                            if (expiry != "none" && expiry != "")
                            {
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expirydate", DateTime.Parse(expiry));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expirydate", Convert.DBNull); 
                            }`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert DateTime and comapre with a string by parsing as follows

```
(DateTime.Parse(date).ToString()=="None" || DateTime.Parse(date).ToString()==String.Empty())?true:False
```

Or you can use a try catch block to validate it.

Comment: Gosh This doesn't work either.I have tried the `DateTime.Parse(row.Cell(4).GetValue<DateTime>()).ToString()=="None" || DateTime.Parse(row.Cell(4).GetValue<DateTime>()).ToString()==String.Empty())`