# Input string not in correct format error during a count with column of only null values

Tags: c#, winforms

I am counting certain int values (1, 2, 3, or 4) in particular columns of a `datatable`. The only values the column can contain are ints between 1 and 9 (exclusive) or null.

For example, a typical column with 10 entries would look like:

```
Level
  1
  2
  1
  4
  3
  7
  3
  3
(null)
  9
```

This works fine, despite the null value. As long as there is a non-null, my code works.

The code fails when the column only contains null values, however, which can happen, as I am pulling this data from a database, and depending on the conditions, all the results may be null.

I am using the code shown below to do this count. I looked at this question: [Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format) yet I am not sure of a way to use `TryParse()` in this context.

```
int countnum = tab2table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => int.Parse(x["Level"].ToString()) == 1 || int.Parse(x["Level"].ToString()) == 2 ||
                                                    int.Parse(x["Level"].ToString()) == 3 || int.Parse(x["Level"].ToString()) == 4).ToList().Count;
```

For the example `Level` column shown above, `countnum` should be 7. When the column is all null `countnum` should be 0.

How can this be changed to work even when the column is all null? I suppose if there were a way to check if the column if null, I could put this in an if statement, but I have not found a way to do that.

Comment: Did you try `x["Level"] != null`?

Comment: @JoséPedro since this is a `DataTable`, they may need to actually check for [DBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.8). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604414/best-way-to-check-if-a-data-table-has-a-null-value-in-it

Comment: @MattBurland if I add ` x["MPerfLevel"] != DBNull.Value && ...` to my code, it still gives me the same error

Comment: `int countnum = tab2table.AsEnumerable().Where(f => f["Level"] != DBNull.Value && (int)f["Level"] > 0 && (int)f["Level"] < 5).Count();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
int countnum = tab2table.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(x => int.TryParse(x["Level"].ToString(), out var d) ? d : (int?)null)
     .Where(x => x >= 1 && x <= 4)
     .Count();
```

Using `TryParse` avoids the problem with null values (or otherwise non-integer values). If `x["Level"]` is null (or `DBNull`) then the selected value will be null. Using `Select` followed by `Where` you also avoid potentially parsing your integers 4 times, which is pretty inefficient, and since you are now dealing with nullable ints, any nulls will always return false in the `where` clause, causing them to be skipped.

If the values in your datatable are actually `int`, then you can just check for `DBNull` and cast your datatable cells to `int`.

Comment: Do you know why it is giving me an error on the `x` in the `Where` clause? It says: `The name 'x' does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch - whoops. My bad. Try it now.

Comment: So how do I make `countnum = 0` if this doesn't work? Because what is exactly to `countnum` when the whole column is `DBnull`?

Comment: If your column is all null values then `countnum` will be zero. Because no cells will pass your `Where` clause.

Comment: Here's what I don't understand, then. How come, when I change my code to anything other than what I'm showing in the actual question, it won't break on all null values, but it also doesn't compute anything with that table properly? For example: `for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {float percent = Convert.ToInt32(tab2table.Compute("COUNT(Level)", "Level =" + i.ToString()));
                    if (countnumRW > 0)
                        tab2tableExtra.Rows[i-1][2] = Math.Round(100 * percent / countnum,2);}` just outputs null

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch - I'm not sure what you are saying. You need to come up with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem you are seeing because as you've described it, this should work.