# How do I correctly check DBNull in VB?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Why does the following code:

```
  A = not IsDBNull(CurRow("BuyBook")) AndAlso CType(CurRow("BuyBook"), string) = "Yes"
```

results in the following error:

```
 Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.
```

When AndAlso is supposed to short-circuit according to this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817250

Comment: Can you try this `A = (not IsDBNull(CurRow("BuyBook"))) AndAlso CType(CurRow("BuyBook"), string) = "Yes"`

Comment: debug the code to see the data inside the cells.

Comment: I've even broken it into two statements and tried. I think IsDBNull is broken.

Comment: Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221582/most-efficient-way-to-check-for-dbnull-and-then-assign-to-a-variable) post.

Comment: Is there any other code related to this operation. if yes then post it.

Comment: What type is CurRow by the way? anIDataReader/SqlDataReader?

Comment: Try NOT (CurRow("BuyBook")) is System.Dbnull.Value, it should work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct. `AndAlso` is short circuiting.

However, the error comes by *calling* `CurRow("GuyBook")` (verify this in a debugger to make sure I'm not a liar or making some crazy assumptions or just misremembering* ;-). Before you ask for a value, you need to ask the DataRow [*if it has a value*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0.aspx). That is, use:

```
CurRow.IsNull("BuyBook")
```

Happy coding.

---

*One *should* just be able to compare with `DBNull.Value` or use `IsDBNull`. However, I am fairly certain that I ran into a row before that threw these exceptions instead of returning a `DBNull` object. Start by finding out -- in the Immediate Window of the Debugger -- exactly *which* expression throws the exception.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried comparing like this:

```
If CurRow("BuyBook") Is DBNull.Value Then
     '...
End If
```

Comment: Yes, I get an exception saying that you can't compare an Object and DBNull type.

Comment: Updated to changed the comparison done to match how its done in some of our code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of not IsDBNull(CurRow("BuyBook")), use NOT (CurRow("BuyBook")) is System.Dbnull.Value). Try this:

```
A = (NOT (CurRow("BuyBook")) is System.Dbnull.Value) AndAlso CType(CurRow("BuyBook"), string) = "Yes"
```

OR

```
A = not string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurRow("BuyBook")) AndAlso CType(CurRow("BuyBook"), string) = "Yes"
```

Comment: I guess you missed this `I've even broken it into two statements and tried`.

Answer (score 0):

```
If dt.Rows(0)("BuyBook") = DBNull.Value Then
End If
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In vb.net I usually do something like this:

```
A = (CurRow("BuyBook") & "" = "Yes")
```

Old trick from vb6 era. If `CurRow("BuyBook")` is null, vb.net will consider it as empty string when concatenating it with another string.

Comment: Doesn't this rely upon Option Strict being off?  I would prefer just using the ToString method directly `CurRow("BuyBook").ToString = "Yes"` if using this solution.