# evaluating DBNull: checking for equality or using the 'is' operator?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a C# question.
I just wanted to ask the community about the use of [System.DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) in conjunction with using a DataReader.

When querying a database and checking for null values, which is more appropriate/preferred?

Using the '[is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)' operator:

```
reader["fieldname"] is DBNull
```

or just checking the value:

```
reader["fieldname"] == DBNull.Value
```

Both seem to work. I just wanted to get some other opinions.

Comment: Why not using [reader.IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx)?

Comment: reader.IsDBNull() requires an integer parameter. I would prefer to use string parameters.

Comment: You can: `reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal("fieldname"))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to check for DBNull and then assign to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221582/most-efficient-way-to-check-for-dbnull-and-then-assign-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 7):

Given that `DBNull.Value` is the only non-null value for the [`DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/934efkk6) class, the two are effectively equivalent. Which do you find more readable? Personally I quite like the first version, but your mileage may vary.

It's unlikely to be a problem in terms of performance either way.

Answer (score 4):

You can check also in this way :

```
Convert.IsDBNull(reader["field name"]);
```

Comment: For the sake of discussion, this is what Convent.IsDBNUll is doing behind the scenes:

public static bool IsDBNull(object value)
{
 if (value == DBNull.Value)
 {
  return true;
 }
 IConvertible convertible = value as IConvertible;
 return convertible != null && convertible.GetTypeCode() == TypeCode.DBNull;
}

Answer (score 2):

I think Microsoft generally recommends using Convert.IsDBNull since they tend to want you to use Convert for most conversion and equivalency checking.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx:

> You can determine whether a value retrieved from a database field is a DBNull value by passing the value of that field to the DBNull.Value.Equals method. However, some languages and database objects supply methods that make it easier to determine whether the value of a database field is DBNull.Value. These include the Visual Basic IsDBNull function, the Convert.IsDBNull method, the DataTableReader.IsDBNull method, and the IDataRecord.IsDBNull method.