# returning a null value from database as a string value

Tags: c#, null, sqlconnection

I am extracting records from a database and some of the fields do not have values (null).

I would like to extract them as string values, how can I do this?

I have tried the following but get an invalid cast exception.

```
string tc = (string)dbread["CustomerAcceptedTerms"]!= DBNull.Value.ToString() ? "Yes": "Null";
```

["CustomerAcceptedTerms"] is a bit value and it can be null

Comment: possible duplicate of [evaluating DBNull: checking for equality or using the 'is' operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103910/evaluating-dbnull-checking-for-equality-or-using-the-is-operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value in the database is null then the value in your code will be DBNull.Value. Compare with that value and dont cast it to a string.

```
string tc = dbread["CustomerAcceptedTerms"] != DBNull.Value ? "Yes" : "Null";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try in this way:

```
string tc = Convert.IsDBNull(dbread["CustomerAcceptedTerms"]) ? "Null": "Yes";
```