# Generic method to read data from DataReader

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am currently using this method to read data from DataReader -

```
private T GetValue<T>(object obj)
{
    if (typeof(DBNull) != obj.GetType())
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

calling above method as -

```
GetValue<int>(dataReader["columnName1"])
GetValue<string>(dataReader["columnName2"])
GetValue<float>(dataReader["columnName3"])
```

However this fails when `columnName3` is having values as `7200000` with error
`Invalid Cast Exception.`

I am thinking to modify my method to replace -

```
return (T)obj;
```

with

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
```

But looking forward for a better way as this change will involve type casting two times.
Any better ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What datatype is columnName3 in the database?

Comment: have you seen Linq to Dataset?

Comment: @RQDQ, it's SQL Server datatype 'real'. I just tried to replicate in console app with following code: object objValue = 7200000; float floatValue = (float)objValue; // fails here

Comment: @Daniel, Linq to Dataset is not the option for now :-(

Comment: Why did you expect casting a real to a string to work? A useful error though as it shows how useful this code will be in the real world. Returning default(T) when the value in the DB is null for value types is a disaster waiting to happen as well.

Comment: @Tony sorry that was a typo :-( corrected now

Comment: @RQDQ, same error with Single (I think Single and float represent same data type in .net framework)

Comment: Hmmm, don't think I've ever used real in all my time with sql server. I think you are going to have to do a specific test for it

Answer (score 4):

A generic method has the advantage that you can reduce a lot of code bloat, but otherwise churning out your own wrapper for each data type gives you the flexibility to have custom handling. And most probably your db queries will have a noticeable effect on performance than mode of retrieval.

I suggest you to write a set of your own extension methods than having one generic approach. Extending the method on `IDataReader` gives you the benefit of not propagating the methods on entire object sub types. I have had to individually handle types since various connectors behaved differently especially with `Guid` type. Also its hard to know if datareader read the value `0` or `DBNull` when you're returning `0` for both cases. Lets say there is an enum field in your table with a null value. why would you ever want it to be read as the first enum?

Just call:

```
dataReader.GetInt("columnName1")
dataReader.GetString("columnName3")
dataReader.GetFloat("columnName3")
```

And the methods:

```
public static int? GetInt(this IDataReader r, string columnName)
{
    var i = r[columnName];      
    if (i.IsNull())
        return null; //or your preferred value

    return (int)i;
}

public static bool IsNull<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    return (object)obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value;
}
```

And similarly,

```
public static string GetString(this IDataReader r, string columnName)
{
}

public static float GetFloat(this IDataReader r, string columnName)
{
}
```

If you really want one generic function you can have it too.

```
public static T Get<T>(this IDataReader r, string columnName, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    var obj = r[columnName];      
    if (obj.IsNull())
        return defaultValue;

    return (T)obj;
}
```

So call it

```
dataReader.Get<int>(1); //if DBNull should be treated as 0
dataReader.Get<int?>(1); //if DBNull should be treated as null
dataReader.Get<int>(1, -1); //if DBNull should be treated as a custom value, say -1
```

That said, the error is because you're not casting with right type as pointed out in comments. I could have gone with built in `DBNull` checks, but I don't to avoid data being read multiple times from the reader, [inspired from this curious case of microoptimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221582/most-efficient-way-to-check-for-dbnull-and-then-assign-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with .NET Framework 4.5

```
static class SqlReaderExtension
{
    public static async Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string fieldName)
    {
        if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", nameof(fieldName));

        int idx = reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        return await reader.GetFieldValueAsync<T>(idx);
    }
}
```

and then

```
string result = await reader.ReadAsync<string>("FieldName");
```