# What is the best way of getting value from a DataRow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

All, I am trying to find a elegant way to retrieve value from a `DataRow`. Below is the way I had tried. please review it .And I think it is not good enough. Because it would be verbose when the number of fields which I want to retrieve is big. Any better idea? thanks.

```
  int result = -1;

  if (row["intCol"] != null)
  {
      bool bresult = int.TryParse(row["intCol"].ToString(), out result);
  }
```

**Updated**

The `intCol` data type in DB is nullable string.

**Updated**

Found it from [Most efficient way to check for DBNull and then assign to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221582/most-efficient-way-to-check-for-dbnull-and-then-assign-to-a-variable)

Cheers.

Comment: if `row["intCol"]` is always an int, you can just do: `int result = (int)row["intCol"]`. other wise, check the type first. int->string->int conversion (what i think you're doing) seems wrong

Comment: If you know what type is supposed to be there - `row.Field<int?>("intCol")` (to avoid failure with `DBNull`)

Comment: Hi Sorry for forgetting to specify the DB type of `intCol`. It is nullable string. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [`IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datarow.isnull%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [`SetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360652%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) methods to avoid dealing with [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx).

In the example you posted, you probably only need `Field`:

```
int? result = row.Field<int?>("intCol");
// if intCol is DBNull.Value, result will now be null.
```

Comment: Beware that the `Field` method will simply cast the value to the specified type. It will not attempt a data type conversion. This means that if the value is actually a `decimal` and you've specified `int`, you'll get an `InvalidCastException`. If you're not entirely certain of the data type at runtime, you should stick to `Convert.ToInt32(row["intCol"])` to allow type conversion.

Comment: ... combined with an `IsNull` check on the column beforehand.

Comment: I see. so why don't use the `tryparse` especially when the original datatype is string . thanks.

Comment: If the original type is a string I would definitely use `TryParse`. `Convert.ToXXX` *can* convert strings for you, but it always uses the user's current  regional settings to determine how to parse numbers and dates.

Comment: Another obvious benefit of using `TryParse` is the fact that it won't fail if string cannot be parsed. `Convert.ToXXX` will throw an exception.

Comment: yes. right . It is the main purpose of the `TryParse`. I found We can use Invariant Culture when trying to parse the number and date. http://forums.asp.net/t/1592165.aspx/1

Comment: Exactly. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `Field<int?>` property to get the result:

```
var result = row.Field<int?>("intCol");
```

Comment: Hi @Cuong Le , What if the value is null in DB? Should we use `int?` or `var` ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use Convert (especially if the type might be also be BIGINT, SMALINT, ..).

```
 var i = Convert.ToInt32(row["intCol"]); // i is a int
```

Beware that would convert NULL into 0.

If you're pretty sure the DB Type is INT (and not BIGINT, SMALINT, ..), use "as" (DB NULL would become null reference)

```
 var i = row["intCol"] as int?; // i is a nullable int
```

Comment: Hi @Serge, In the worst case . DB type could be nullable string. I think.

Comment: Then use "Convert" after you checked row["intCol"] == DBNull.Value ?