# Null-Conditional not working for database record

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.6, null-conditional-operator

I'm trying to test out the new [Null-Conditional operator](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-VB-14#null-conditional-operators) in .NET 4.6 (using VB.Net), but it isn't working for me when retrieving null values from fields of a database record, and I can't understand why. Here's my code:

```
Dim dbtable As New DataSet1.MyDataTable
Dim dbrecord As DataSet1.MyRecord

dbrecord = dbtable.NewMyDataTableRow
Dim val = dbrecord.CustomerName?.ToString
```

Yet, it still throws a System.Data.StrongTypingException.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to check for DBNull and then assign to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221582/most-efficient-way-to-check-for-dbnull-and-then-assign-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `CustomerName`'s value is `DBNull`, not `null`.  See what the documentation on [StrongTypingException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.strongtypingexception.aspx) says:

> The exception that is thrown by a strongly typed `DataSet` when the user accesses a **`DBNull`** value.

The null-conditional operator can't help you with a `DBNull` value.

I think you have no choice but to manually check for `dbrecord.IsCustomerNameNull` (you should have a property named like that) before attempting to read `CustomerName`.

Comment: to complete @sstan answer you can check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221582/most-efficient-way-to-check-for-dbnull-and-then-assign-to-a-variable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround that isn't as cumbersome as always checking `IsCustomerNameNull`. Use this instead:

```
Dim val = dbrecord("CustomerName")?.ToString
```