# Are there compelling reasons AGAINST using the C# keyword "as"?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, types, as-keyword

I find that using the following:

```
TreeViewItem i = sender as TreeViewItem;
if(i != null){ ... }
```

is easier to write and understand than:

```
if(sender.GetType() == typeof(TreeViewItem)){
    TreeViewItem i = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    ...
}
```

Are there compelling reasons *not* to use the first construct?

Comment: sender.GetType() == typeof(TreeViewItem) is not the same thing as 'sender as TreeViewItem'. That test fails to take the inheritance hierarchy into account, something 'as' and 'is' keyword does.

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr/496167#496167

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer casts to `as` in most cases because usually if the type of the object is wrong, that indicates a bug. Bugs *should* cause exceptions IMO - and an `InvalidCastException` at exactly the line which performs the cast is a lot clearer than a `NullReferenceException`much later in the code.

`as` should be used when it's valid and legal to have been passed a reference to an object of the type that you don't want. That situation does come up, but not as often as normal casting in my experience.

Comparing types using `GetType()`, however, is very rarely the right solution - it's only appropriate when you want to check for the *exact* type involved rather than a compatible type.

I've written a [significantly longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr/496167#496167) about the "cast vs as" discussion elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Not at all - it gives you the chance to verify that the conversion (cast) was done OK. If you do

```
TreeViewItem i = (TreeViewItem) sender;
```

you might get an exception if the cast fails.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, these two snippets are *not* equivalent. `TreeViewItem i = sender as TreeViewItem` will yield a correct result even if `sender` is a grand-grand-child of `TreeViewItem`, whereas `sender.GetType() == typeof(TreeViewItem)` will be `true` *only* when `sender` is precisely `TreeViewItem` and none of its possible subclasses.

Answer (score 4):

"as": good stuff. use it all the time.

if you really want an alternative to manually comparing types try:

```
  if(person is Employee) { }
```

reads better yet.

Answer (score 4):

Your example would be better written as:

```
if (sender is TreeViewItem) {
    TreeViewItem i = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    ...
}
```

It is exactly this dual type checking that the `as` operator can help avoid. So for your cited example, I would say it is definitely a good solution.

However, there are situations where you really *do* want a cast. If you're expecting a `TreeViewItem` and want nothing else, casting will ensure an `InvalidCastException` is thrown if you're given anything else.

Just like in most situations, there is no blanket rule here: **use the right tool for the right job**.

Comment: This form can also cause issues when multithreaded as the object can change type between the is cast check and the regular cast.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a plain (not nullable) value type, obviously this won't work, eg:

```
int test = sender as int;
```

isn't valid, however:

```
int? test = sender as int?;
```

is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

"as" is faster, but things to bear in mind are:

- "as" returns a null instead of throwing an exception if that's a problem
- it won't do custom conversions iirc
- it doesn't work for reference->value

Edit: "as" definitely is faster (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpcasts.aspx)

Edit2: so basically a speed vs safety decision

Answer (score 1):

No, I use it quite a bit.  It allows you to avoid `InvalidCastException`s in a clean way.

For example:

```
TreeViewItem tvItem = sender as TreeViewItem;

if (tvItem != null) return;

// Do stuff
```

as opposed to:

```
try
{
    TreeViewItem tvItem = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    // Do stuff.
}
catch (InvalidCastException ex)
{
    // Didn't work, do something about it
    return; // ... or not...
}
```

Comment: Can you think of any reason that "sender" would not be a TreeViewItem other than a bug, in most cases? Bugs *should* raise exceptions IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If getting the wrong type would be a bug, then you should use a cast. The reason for this is that there really is a problem and you should know about it.

If it is possible that the value will be null, and that is not a bug in the system when this happens then use "as". The reason being that you should use "as" any time that getting a null back is acceptable.

Keep in mind that you can't use "as" to convert to value types, because the null value is not acceptable for them. If you have a value type and want to use "as", you will need to use a nullable value type.

[When to Use "as" Versus Casting](http://aspalliance.com/1811_Standard_Type_Casting_and_as_Operator_Conversions.3)