# Why does "as T" get an error but casting with (T) not get an error?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting, generic-programming

Why can I do this:

```
public T GetMainContentItem<T>(string moduleKey, string itemKey)
{
    return (T)GetMainContentItem(moduleKey, itemKey);
}
```

but not this:

```
public T GetMainContentItem<T>(string moduleKey, string itemKey)
{
    return GetMainContentItem(moduleKey, itemKey) as T;
}
```

It complains that I haven't restricted the generic type enough, but then I would think that rule would apply to casting with "(T)" as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because 'T' could be a value-type and 'as T' makes no sense for value-types. You can do this:

```
public T GetMainContentItem<T>(string moduleKey, string itemKey)
    where T : class
{
    return GetMainContentItem(moduleKey, itemKey) as T;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, you can cast on value types, the result will be nullable, see this post and the answer by Jon Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr

Answer (score 6):

If T is a value type this is an exception, you need to make sure T is either Nullable or a class.

Answer (score 1):

Is `T` a value type?  If so, if the `as` operator fails, it will return `null`, which cannot be stored in a value type.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Yuriy Faktorovichs answer:

```
public T GetMainContentItem<T>(string moduleKey, string itemKey) where T: class
{
    return GetMainContentItem(moduleKey, itemKey) as T;
}
```

This will do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Because `as T` retrieves `null` in case that it cannot cast to `T` as opposed to `(T)` that throws an exception. So if `T` is not `Nullable` or `class` it can't be `null` ... i think.