# C# Interface with multiple functions defined

Tags: c#, interface

Can some one help me understand why this doesn't work:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    string GetString(string start);
    void DoSomething();
}

public class InterfaceImpl : IInterface
{
    string IInterface.GetString(string start)
    {
        return start + " okay.";
    }
    void IInterface.DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetString("Go")); // <-- Error: InterfaceImpl does not contain a definition for GetString
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why I can't call a function that is most certainly defined in the implementation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider also reading [interfaces overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) on MSDN - you may not need explicit implementation as cruellays' answer points out.

Answer (score 5):

Explicitly implemented methods need to be called on variable of interface type, usually with cast:

```
   Console.WriteLine(((IInterface)this).GetString("Go"));
```

More variants of calling explicitly defined methods are covered in [How to call explicit interface implementation methods internally without explicit casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868861/how-to-call-explicit-interface-implementation-methods-internally-without-explici)

Answer (score 5):

you do not need to explicitly specify the Interface with the method. Since InterfaceImpl is already implementing IInterface, you just need to do as follows:

```
public class InterfaceImpl : IInterface
{
    public string GetString(string start)
    {
        return start + " okay.";
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetString("Go"));
    }
}
```

Updated as per comment.

Comment: Those methods should be marked `public`, otherwise this doesn't implement the interface.