# How do I safely cast a System.Object to a `bool` in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I am extracting a `bool` value from a (non-generic, heterogeneous) collection.

The `as` operator may only be used with reference types, so it is not possible to do use `as` to try a safe-cast to `bool`:

```
// This does not work: "The as operator must be used with a reference type ('bool' is a value type)"
object rawValue = map.GetValue(key);
bool value = rawValue as bool;
```

Is there something similar that can be done to safely cast an object to a value type without possibility of an `InvalidCastException` if, for whatever reason, the value is not a boolean?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

There are two options... with slightly surprising performance:

- Redundant checking:

  ```
  if (rawValue is bool)
  {
      bool x = (bool) rawValue;
      ...
  }
  ```
- Using a nullable type:

  ```
  bool? x = rawValue as bool?;
  if (x != null)
  {
      ... // use x.Value
  }
  ```

The surprising part is that the [performance of the second form is much worse than the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types).

In C# 7, you can use pattern matching for this:

```
if (rawValue is bool value)
{
    // Use value here
}
```

Note that you still end up with `value` in scope (but not definitely assigned) after the `if` statement.

Comment: I found the C# docs helpful to explain the 'is' operator.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is

Answer (score 21):

Like this:

```
if (rawValue is bool) {
    bool value = (bool)rawValue;
    //Do something
} else {
    //It's not a bool
}
```

Unlike reference types, there's no fast way to try to cast to a value type without two casts.  (Or a catch block, which would be worse)

Comment: @SLaks: See mine and kalusbyskov's answers for alternatives to using two casts. Not that it really helps.

Answer (score 9):

With C# 9 you can also simplify to:

```
if(rawValue is true)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Does this check the object for being a `bool` first and returns false if it's not?

Answer (score 8):

```
bool value;
if(rawValue is bool)
  value = (bool)rawValue;
else {
  // something is not right...
```

Answer (score 5):

You haven't defined what you want to have happen if rawValue is not convertible to bool. Common choices are to return false, null, or throw an exception. There's also the possibility of the string representation of rawValue to be convertible to a bool, such as Yes/No, True/False, 1/0, etc.

I would use bool.TryParse to do the conversion. This will succeed if rawValue is a bool or its string value is "True" or "False".

```
bool result;
if (!bool.TryParse(rawValue as string, out result))
{
    // you need to decide what to do in this case
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can cast it to a `bool?` with the `as` keyword and check the `HasValue` property.

Answer (score 1):

Providing you don't actually need to keep a reference to the `rawValue`, here's a one-liner using the [`GetValueOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) structure:

```
bool value = (map.GetValue(key) as bool?).GetValueOrDefault();
```

You can also specify a default value using the method overload [`GetValueOrDefault(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to have **true** only if the raw object is boolean '**true**' then one-liner `(rawValue as bool?)?? false` will do:

```
object rawValue=null
(rawValue as bool?)?? false
false
rawValue="some string"
(rawValue as bool?)?? false
false
rawValue=true
(rawValue as bool?)?? false
true
rawValue="true"
(rawValue as bool?)?? false
false
rawValue=false
(rawValue as bool?)?? false
false
rawValue=""
(rawValue as bool?)?? false
false
rawValue=1
(rawValue as bool?)?? false
false
rawValue=new Dictionary<string,string>()
(rawValue as bool?)?? false
false`
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this check before doing something with **object**

```
if(myCrazyObject.GetType().Equals(typeof(bool)))
{
   //do smt with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool value = (rawValue is null) ? false : (bool)rawValue.value;
```

if rawValue is `null` then value will be `false`, otherwise value will receive the correct boolean value.

Answer (score -3):

You can also try Convert.ToBoolean(rowValue);

Comment: This will throw an exception if the type is not a convertible to a boolean, and it also will try to convert non-boolean values into a boolean if it can, which is not what the requirements state should happen.

Comment: Oops. I so was not paying attention here. Thanks!