# C# Convert a generic object into a boolean

Tags: c#

I'm reading in data from a sqlite reader. It's returning an `object`, most of them I know are `boolean`. What's the best way to convert `object` into a `boolean`?

Comment: If you know it is a `boolean`, you should be able to just cast it: `var yourobj = (bool)valuefromreader;`

Comment: For some reason that didn't seem to work, but I guess it does. I think I was trying to convert it to a string at the same time. thanks

Comment: nevermind. I get an invalid cast when I try to cast it like `var obj = (bool)reader["field"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably go through `TryParse`. Otherwise you run the risk of throwing an exception. But it depends on how your system is written.

```
object x;

bool result = false;

if(bool.TryParse(string.Format("{0}", x), out result))
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Alternatively you can do a direct cast:

```
bool result = (bool)x;
```

Or use the `Convert` class:

```
bool result = Convert.ToBoolean(x);
```

Or you can use a `Nullable<bool>` type:

```
var result = x as bool?;
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you'll probably want the [as operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx). Keep in mind, your type would be a `bool?`.

Comment: I thought this would work and is what I first tried, but I do need a `bool`, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
bool? val = YourValue as bool?;
if (val != null)
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must have a final `bool` value, for C# 7.0 (introduced in 2017) and later, a compact syntax is:

```
bool myBool = (myObject as bool?) ?? false;
```

So this might be "best" from the standpoint of brevity. But code using the `is` operator performs better (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076525)). In this case, the following may be preferred:

```
bool myBool = myObject is bool ? (bool)myObject : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it.

```
var boolValue = (bool)yourObject;
```

Comment: this is not a good way because it will throw exception on fail. use tryParse

Answer (score 0):

If you want case an object to a boolean type, you simply need to check if the object `is` a bool, then cast it, like so:

```
if (someObject is bool)
{
    bool someBool = (bool)someObject;
    ...
}
```

As a side note, it is not possible to use the `as` operator on a non-reference type (because it cannot be null). This question may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974922/how-do-i-safely-cast-a-system-object-to-a-bool-in-c) one.