# How to invalidate cache when benchmarking?

Tags: c, caching, benchmarking, cache-invalidation

I have this code, that when swapping the order of UsingAs and UsingCast, their performance also swaps.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

using System.IO;

class Test
{
    const int Size = 30000000;

    static void Main()
    {
        object[] values = new MemoryStream[Size];



        UsingAs(values);
        UsingCast(values);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void UsingCast(object[] values)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (object o in values)
        {
            if (o is MemoryStream)
            {
                var m = (MemoryStream)o;
                sum += (int)m.Length;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Cast: {0} : {1}", sum,
                          (long)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    static void UsingAs(object[] values)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (object o in values)
        {

            if (o is MemoryStream)
            {
                var m = o as MemoryStream;
                sum += (int)m.Length;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("As: {0} : {1}", sum,
                          (long)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }


}
```

Outputs:

```
As: 0 : 322
Cast: 0 : 281
```

When doing this...

```
UsingCast(values);
UsingAs(values);
```

...Results to this:

```
Cast: 0 : 322
As: 0 : 281
```

When doing just this...

```
UsingAs(values);
```

...Results to this:

```
As: 0 : 322
```

When doing just this:

```
UsingCast(values);
```

...Results to this:

```
Cast: 0 : 322
```

Aside from running them independently, how to **invalidate** the cache so the second code being benchmarked won't receive the cached memory of first code?

Benchmarking aside, just loved the fact that modern processors do this caching magic :-)

**[EDIT]**

As advised to try this faster code(supposedly)...

```
static void UsingAsAndNullTest(object[] values)
{        
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (object o in values)
    {
        var m = o as MemoryStream;
        if (m != null)
        {                
            sum += (int)m.Length;
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("As and null test: {0} : {1}", sum,
                      (long)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

...The result is this:

```
As and null test: 0 : 342
```

Slower than the two codes above

**[EDIT]:**

As advised to hand each routine their own copy...

```
static void UsingAs(object[] values)
{
    object[] a = values.ToArray();

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (object o in a)
    {

        if (o is MemoryStream)
        {
            var m = o as MemoryStream;
            sum += (int)m.Length;
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("As: {0} : {1}", sum,
                      (long)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

static void UsingCast(object[] values)
{
    object[] a = values.ToArray();

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (object o in a)
    {
        if (o is MemoryStream)
        {
            var m = (MemoryStream)o;
            sum += (int)m.Length;
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Cast: {0} : {1}", sum,
                      (long)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

...Outputs:

```
Cast: 0 : 282
As: 0 : 282
```

Now they have the same results, thanks Remus!

Running Cast and As independently, they also yield the same result(i.e. 282). Now, as for why they become **faster** (from 322 down to 282 milliseconds) when they are handed their own copy of array, I can't make anything out of it :-)  That's entirely another story

Comment: You know that the fastest way is to not check for `is`, use the `as` operator and test the result for `==null`.

Comment: I'm not asking about how to make the code faster. I'm asking how to make proper benchmarking.  And I have an inkling that somebody will suggest using `as` and test for `==null` (well somebody have), sad to say, that approach is slower than both of the two codes above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take out of the picture the L2 cache and the TLB misses then simply call the second test on a different MemoryStream of the same size.