# How can I tell if an object's type is Nullable<T> using reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection, nullable

If I have a `Type`, is there some easy way to tell that it represents a nullable value type using Reflection? Ideally something a little cleaner (and more correct) than:

```
static bool IsNullable(Type type)
{
    return type.IsValueType && type.Name.StartsWith("Nullable");
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
```

You might also find `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(Type nullableType)` useful, to easily get the `T` of the `typeof(Nullable<T>)` you pass in.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. (I always forget about `<>` in reflection.)

Comment: This will not work in many common situations since the CLR treats `Nullable<T>` as a special type. In particular, it gets boxed into a boxed `T`.

Comment: @Ani: what do you mean? By `T`, I am referring to the `typeof(T)`

Answer (score 7):

Although @theCoop's answer is correct (there is nothing fundamentally *wrong* in placing his code into the body of the method you've provided), there are some giant gotchas here.

`Nullable<T>` is treated by the run-time as a 'special' type that has some very peculiar semantics. In particular, when a `Nullable<T>`is boxed:

1. If `HasValue == true`, it behaves just like a boxed `T`, making it **impossible for downsteam code to tell if the created object was produced by boxing a `T` or by boxing a `Nullable<T>`**. 
   Unboxing to `T` and `Nullable<T>` are both possible.
2. If `HasValue == false`, boxing simply returns `null`. Unboxing to `T` will throw, unboxing to `Nullable<T>` will succeed, for which  `HasValue == false`.

In either case, `boxedNullableObject.GetType()` will not reveal that the object was produced by boxing a `Nullable<T>.` I can't think of any other value-type that exhibits such strange behaviour.

For example, consider:

```
// Output: "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]"
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?));


object boxedNullableInt32WithValue = new int?(0);

// Output: "System.Int32", NOT "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]"
Console.WriteLine(boxedNullableInt32WithValue.GetType()); 


object boxedNullableInt32WithoutValue = new int?();

// NullReferenceException is thrown
Console.WriteLine(boxedNullableInt32WithoutValue.GetType());
```

Consequently, writing a method such as:

`public static bool IsObjectANullableT(this object obj) { ... }`

is a really bad idea.

**EDIT**: On another note, I just realized there is a framework method that does what you need using the same technique as @theCoop's sample:[`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx).

Usage:

```
static bool IsNullable(Type type)
{
    return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
}
```

**EDIT**: Just saw that this too was mentioned by @TheCoop in his answer. My mistake.

Comment: Very helpful and important points to mention. Fortunately, I was specifically looking to identify if the `PropertyType` property of a `PropertyInfo` was some nullable type; in this case, thecoop's answer works great. But you're right that [no other value type behaves that way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775582/how-is-the-boxing-unboxing-behavior-of-nullablet-possible).

Comment: Haha, that's brilliant: you point me to another question of *yours* that deals with this very matter, except with more clarity and detail. What an exercise in redundancy on my part.

Comment: Not at all! I don't think this answer is redundant; it provides some very important insight into the potential pitfalls of a general solution for the problem I posed in my question. I only included that link because I felt it touched on some of the same issues, for those seeking further information.

Comment: it was also useful because I didn't see the other question until seeing this. I learnt something new today. :)