# How is it that an enum derives from System.Enum and is an integer at the same time?

Tags: .net, inheritance, enums, clr, unboxing

**Edit**: Comments at bottom. Also, [this](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/for-the-last-time-you-cant-unbox-a-value-type-as-a-diff%E2%80%94wait-whats-this/).

---

Here's what's kind of confusing me. My understanding is that if I have an enum like this...

```
enum Animal
{
    Dog,
    Cat
}
```

...what I've essentially done is defined a *value type* called `Animal` with two defined values, `Dog` and `Cat`. This type derives from the *reference type* `System.Enum` (something which value types can't normally do—at least not in C#—but which is permitted in this case), and has a facility for casting back and forth to/from `int` values.

If the way I just described the enum type above were true, then I would expect the following code to throw an `InvalidCastException`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Box it.
        object animal = Animal.Dog;

        // Unbox it. How are these both successful?
        int i = (int)animal;
        Enum e = (Enum)animal;

        // Prints "0".
        Console.WriteLine(i);

        // Prints "Dog".
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

**Normally, [you cannot unbox a value type from `System.Object` as anything other than its exact type](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/the-difference-between-converting-and-unboxing-read-my-mind-compiler/).** So how is the above possible? It is as if the `Animal` type **is** an `int` (not just *convertible* to `int`) and **is** an `Enum` (not just *convertible* to `Enum`) at the same time. <strike>Is it multiple inheritance? Does `System.Enum` somehow inherit from `System.Int32` (something I would not have expected to be possible)?</strike>

**Edit**: It can't be either of the above. The following code demonstrates this (I think) conclusively:

```
object animal = Animal.Dog;

Console.WriteLine(animal is Enum);
Console.WriteLine(animal is int);
```

The above outputs:

```
True
False
```

Both [the MSDN documentation on enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and the C# specification make use of the term "underlying type"; but I don't know what this means, nor have I ever heard it used in reference to anything other than enums. What does "underlying type" actually *mean*?

---

So, is this yet another [case that gets special treatment from the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775582/how-is-the-boxing-unboxing-behavior-of-nullablet-possible)?

My money's on that being the case... but an answer/explanation would be nice.

---

**Update**: [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626394/how-is-it-that-an-enum-derives-from-system-enum-and-is-an-integer-at-the-same-tim/4627345#4627345) provided the reference to truly answer this question. The explanation can be found in Partition II of the CLI specification, in the section on enums:

> For binding purposes (e.g., for
>   locating a method definition from the
>   method reference used to call it)
>   enums shall be distinct from their
>   underlying type.  For all other
>   purposes, including verification and
>   execution of code, **an unboxed enum
>   freely interconverts with its
>   underlying type**.  Enums can be boxed
>   to a corresponding boxed instance
>   type, but this type is *not* the same
>   as the boxed type of the underlying
>   type, so boxing does not lose the
>   original type of the enum.

**Edit (again?!)**: Wait, actually, I don't know that I read that right the first time. Maybe it doesn't 100% explain the specialized unboxing behavior itself (though I'm leaving Damien's answer as accepted, as it shed a great deal of light on this issue). I will continue looking into this...

---

**Another Edit**: Man, then [yodaj007's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626394/how-is-it-that-an-enum-derives-from-system-enum-and-is-an-integer-at-the-same-tim/4627416#4627416) threw me for another loop. Somehow an enum is not exactly the same as an `int`; yet an `int` can be assigned to an enum variable *with no cast*? Buh?

I think this is all ultimately illuminated by [Hans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626394/how-is-it-that-an-enum-derives-from-system-enum-and-is-an-integer-at-the-same-tim/4627431#4627431), which is why I've accepted it. (Sorry, Damien!)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, special treatment.  The JIT compiler is keenly aware of the way boxed value types work.  Which is in general what makes value types acting a bit schizoid.  Boxing involves creating a System.Object value that behaves exactly the same way as a value of a reference type.  At that point, value type values no longer behave like values do at runtime.  Which makes it possible, for example, to have a virtual method like ToString().  The boxed object has a method table pointer, just like reference types do.

The JIT compiler knows the method tables pointers for value types like int and bool up front.  Boxing and unboxing for them is *very* efficient, it takes but a handful of machine code instructions.  This needed to be efficient back in .NET 1.0 to make it competitive.  A *very* important part of that is the restriction that a value type value can only be unboxed to the same type.  This avoids the jitter from having to generate a massive switch statement that invokes the correct conversion code.  All it has to do is to check the method table pointer in the object and verify that it is the expected type.  And copy the value out of the object directly.  Notable perhaps is that this restriction doesn't exist in VB.NET, its CType() operator does in fact generate code to a helper function that contains this big switch statement.

The problem with Enum types is that this cannot work.  Enums can have a different GetUnderlyingType() type.  In other words, the unboxed value has different sizes so simply copying the value out of the boxed object cannot work.  Keenly aware, the jitter doesn't inline the unboxing code anymore, it generates a call to a helper function in the CLR.

That helper is named JIT_Unbox(), you can find its source code in the SSCLI20 source, clr/src/vm/jithelpers.cpp.  You'll see it dealing with enum types specially.  It is permissive, it allows unboxing from one enum type to another.  But only if the underlying type is the same, you get an InvalidCastException if that's not the case.

Which is also the reason that Enum is declared as a class.  Its *logical* behavior is of a reference type, derived enum types can be cast from one to another.  With the above noted restriction on the underlying type compatibility. The values of an enum type have however very much the behavior of a value type value.  They have copy semantics and boxing behavior.

Comment: Awesome info. I feel like I learn like 25 new things every time I read one of your answers...

Comment: Hans Passant, but **why** did they choose to "allow enums and their primtive type to be interchangable" as the comment says in the C++ code? Please see my new question on combined unboxing and enum conversion (my question linked to this older question).

Comment: The problem is that you assume the C# unboxing conversion behaves the normal way.  It is the opposite, it is the exceptional way.  Check this answer for the reason why it is exceptional: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types/3076525#3076525

Answer (score 9):

Enums are specially dealt with by the CLR. If you want to go into the gory details, you can download the [MS Partition II](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/3/733AD403-90B2-4064-A81E-01035A7FE13C/MS%20Partition%20II.pdf) spec. In it, you'll find that Enums:

> Enums obey additional restrictions
>   beyond those on other value types.
>   Enums shall contain only fields as
>   members (they shall not even define
>   type initializers or instance
>   constructors); they shall not
>   implement any interfaces; they
>   shall have auto field layout
>   (§10.1.2); they shall have exactly one
>   instance field and it shall be of the underlying type of
>   the enum; all other fields shall be
>   static and literal (§16.1);

So that's how they can inherit from System.Enum, but have an "underlying" type - it's the single instance field they're allowed to have.

There is also a discussion on boxing behaviour, but it doesn't describe explicitly unboxing to the underlying type, that I can see.

Comment: I sense that we are definitely getting closer with this answer; thanks. I am taking a look at that spec now; do you happen to know if it includes a special allowance for unboxing an enum to that single instance field you mentioned?

Comment: This totally nailed it down for me. I even found the part where it explicitly defines the unboxing behavior, which I will add as an update. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry, man... even though this was a really helpful answer, I think I have to change horses and give this one to Hans, whose answer *really* helped clarify this for me. You got robbed!

Answer (score 4):

What I'm noting here is from page 38 of [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (I suggest you download it just to have it):

> The CTS supports an enum (also known as an enumeration type), an alternate name for an existing type. For the purposes of matching signatures, an enum shall not be the same as the underlying type. Instances of an enum, however, shall be assignable-to the underlying type, and vice versa. That is, no cast (see §8.3.3) or coercion (see §8.3.2) is required to convert from the enum to the underlying type, nor are they required from the underlying type to the enum. An enum is considerably more restricted than a true type, as follows:
>
> The underlying type shall be a built-in integer type. Enums shall derive from System.Enum, hence they are value types. Like all value types, they shall be sealed (see §8.9.9).

```
enum Foo { Bar = 1 }
Foo x = Foo.Bar;
```

This statement will be false because of the second sentence:

```
x is int
```

They *are* the same (an alias), but their signature is not the same.  Converting to and from an `int` isn't a cast.

From page 46:

> underlying types – in the CTS enumerations are alternate names for existing types (§8.5.2), termed their underlying type. Except for signature matching (§8.5.2) enumerations are treated as their underlying type. This subset is the set of storage types with the enumerations removed.

Go back to my Foo enum earlier.  This statement will work:

```
Foo x = (Foo)5;
```

If you inspect the generated IL code of my Main method in Reflector:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
.entrypoint
.maxstack 1
.locals init (
    [0] valuetype ConsoleTesting.Foo x)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: ldc.i4.5 
L_0002: stloc.0 
L_0003: call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
L_0008: pop 
L_0009: ret 
}
```

Note there's no cast.  `ldc` is found on page 86.  It loads a constant.  `i4` is found on page 151, indicating the type is a 32-bit integer.  There isn't a cast!

Comment: Gahhh... now you are just confusing my poor mind. It seems the CLI spec somehow defines enums as *not* being the same as their "underlying type" (and deriving from `System.Enum`) while somehow also *being the same* at the same time. I don't know what to believe anymore...

Comment: @Dan, that's why I'm here.  Now that my work is done, it's time for lunch.

Answer (score 4):

Partition I, 8.5.2 states that enums are "an alternate name for an existing type" but "[f]or the purposes of matching signatures, an enum shall not be the same as the underlying type."

Partition II, 14.3 expounds: "For all other purposes, including verification and execution of code, an unboxed enum freely interconverts with its underlying type. Enums can be boxed to a corresponding boxed instance type, but this type is not the same as the boxed type of the underlying type, so boxing does not lose the original type of the enum."

Partition III, 4.32 explains the unboxing behavior: "The type of *value type* contained within *obj* must be assignment compatible with *valuetype*. [Note: This effects the behavior with enum types, see Partition II.14.3. end note]"

Answer (score 3):

Extracted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int. By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.

So, the cast is possible, but you need to force it:

> The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each enumerator. However, an explicit cast is needed to convert from enum type to an integral type.

When you box your enum into `object`, the animal object is derived from `System.Enum` (the real type is known at runtime) so it's actually an `int`, so the cast is valid.

- `(animal is Enum)` returns `true`: For this reason you can unbox animal into an Enum or event into an int doing an explicit casting.
- `(animal is int)` returns `false`: The `is` operator (in general type check) does not check the underlying type for Enums. Also, for this reason you need to do an explicit casting to convert Enum to int.

Comment: OK, but if I check `if (animal is Enum)` I get `true`, whereas if I check `if (animal is int)` I get `false`. This is what is confusing me (together with the fact that I can unbox from `object` to `int`). Maybe I should add this to the question...

Comment: An explicit cast from `long` to `int` is possible, but [you cannot unbox a boxed `long` as an `int`](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/the-difference-between-converting-and-unboxing-read-my-mind-compiler/). This was my point; actually *unboxing* an `Enum` as an `int` is legal, which cannot be explained simply by an explicit cast. I think your answer is correct, but I feel like you are sort of missing what I was actually asking. (See my update in response to Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer to see what I mean.)

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I'm playing with reflector and `Enum.Parse`. This call returns an object, and maybe your question is the same. At the end of the call, this method calls to ` InternalBoxEnum(Type enumType, long value);` But, you're right, I did not give the real answer, but it seems to be another CRL special case.

Answer (score 2):

While enum types are inherited from `System.Enum`, any conversion between them is not direct, but a boxing/unboxing one. From C# 3.0 Specification:

> An enumeration type is a distinct type
>   with named constants. Every
>   enumeration type has an underlying
>   type, which must be byte, sbyte,
>   short, ushort, int, uint, long or
>   ulong. The set of values of the
>   enumeration type is the same as the
>   set of values of the underlying type.
>   Values of the enumeration type are not
>   restricted to the values of the named
>   constants. Enumeration types are
>   defined through enumeration
>   declarations

So, while your Animal class is derived from `System.Enum`, it's actually an `int`. Btw, another strange thing is `System.Enum` is derived from `System.ValueType`, however it's still a reference type.

Comment: "Derived from `System.Enum`, but *is* an `int`": this is what I am failing to understand! Can you possibly elaborate on *what this actually means*? (In particular I don't think I have a clear notion of what "underlying type" means. Clearly it is not the same as "base type.")

Comment: This is a guess: It's probably like the duality of int and System.Int32. While storing and doing basic arithmetic it acts like a value, and when needed it acts like a reference type.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple, based on the fact that `animal is int` evaluates to `false` (see my edit).

Comment: Wait, also, did you know that `int` is just an alias for `System.Int32`? There is literally no difference between them (there is no "them"—only "it"); it isn't like `int` and `Integer` in Java.

Comment: Yes, I know int is an alias, however I do not know how to tell the distiction between when it's an int and when it's an object.

Answer (score 1):

A `Enum`'s underlying type is the type used to store the value of the constants. In your example, even though you haven't explicitly defined the values, C# does this:

```
enum Animal : int
{
    Dog = 0,
    Cat = 1
}
```

Internally, `Animal` is made up of two constants with the integer values 0 and 1. That's why you can explicitly cast an integer to an `Animal` and an `Animal` to an integer. If you pass `Animal.Dog` to a parameter that accepts an `Animal`, what you are really doing is passing the 32bit integer value of `Animal.Dog` (in this case, 0). If you give `Animal` a new underlying type, then the values are stored as that type.

Answer (score 1):

Why not... it is perfectly valid, for example, for a structure to hold an int internally, and be convertible to int with an explicit cast operator... lets simulate an Enum:

```
interface IEnum { }

struct MyEnumS : IEnum
{
    private int inner;

    public static explicit operator int(MyEnumS val)
    {
        return val.inner;
    }

    public static explicit operator MyEnumS(int val)
    {
        MyEnumS result;
        result.inner = val;
        return result;
    }

    public static readonly MyEnumS EnumItem1 = (MyEnumS)0;
    public static readonly MyEnumS EnumItem2 = (MyEnumS)2;
    public static readonly MyEnumS EnumItem3 = (MyEnumS)10;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return inner == 0 ? "EnumItem1" :
            inner == 2 ? "EnumItem2" :
            inner == 10 ? "EnumItem3" :
            inner.ToString();
    }
}
```

This struct can be used quite the same way a struct can... of course, if you try to reflect the type, and call IsEnum property it will return false.

Let's look at some usage comparison, with the equivalent enum:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    EnumItem1 = 0,
    EnumItem2 = 2,
    EnumItem3 = 10,
}
```

Comparing usages:

Struct version:

```
var val = MyEnum.EnumItem1;
val = (MyEnum)50;
val = 0;
object obj = val;
bool isE = obj is MyEnum;
Enum en = val;
```

Enum version:

```
var valS = MyEnumS.EnumItem1;
valS = (MyEnumS)50;
//valS = 0; // cannot simulate this
object objS = valS;
bool isS = objS is MyEnumS;
IEnum enS = valS;
```

Some operations cannot be simulated, but this all shows what I intended to say... Enums are special, yes... how much special? not that much! =)