# Nullable create via reflection with HasValue = false

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

Given a type parameter which is a `Nullable<>`, how can I create an instance of that type which has `HasValue` = false?

In other words, complete this code:

```
public static Nullable<T> Create<T>() where T : struct 
{
    //Instantatie a Nullable<T> with reflection whose HasValue = false, and return it
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake asking this question and have reposted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627013/nullable-create-via-reflection-with-hasvalue-false-given-a-parameter-of-type

Comment: @Jamiec The two questions are different: one is `Create<T>()`, while the other is `Create(Type type)`. While `return null` is a solution for both, the questions are surely different.

Comment: @xanatos - this question should probably be deleted by the OP (In actual fact I tried to get him to just update this question - see below). In any case this question is now defunct and should no longer attract answers. Finally, feel free to cast a re-open vote if you disagree, im not the dictator off all things right ;)

Comment: @Jamiec I don't see why it couldn't still be helpful to someone else, which is why I didn't want to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reflection needed in this case.

```
public static Nullable<T> Create<T>() where T : struct 
{
    return new Nullable<T>(); // or default(Nullable<T>) 
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/CHRRM73303

Comment: I made a mistake in my question. While your post answers the question it doesn't solve my problem so will have to start a new question.

Comment: @IanNewson - or you could just update this question.

Comment: I've created the other question, it doesn't seem fair to change the existing question since it's not your fault your perfectly valid answer doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
return default(Nullable<T>)
```

is enough.

or even

```
return null;
```

or even

```
return new Nullable<T>();
```

Nullable value types have the paradox that `new Nullable<T>() == null`

Comment: Can't you just `return null;`?

Comment: @petelids Nullable<T> is structure - can't return null

Comment: @NValchev Yes, it can :-) see https://ideone.com/WPKO5J

Comment: @NValchev - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775582/how-is-the-boxing-unboxing-behavior-of-nullablet-possible) for details. (+1 BTW xanatos!)