# Nullable create via reflection with HasValue = false, given a parameter of type `Type` only

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

Given a type parameter which is a `Nullable<>`, how can I create an instance of that type which has `HasValue = false`?

In other words, complete this code:

```
//type is guaranteed to implement Nullable<>
public static object Create(Type type)
{
    //Instantiate a Nullable<T> with reflection whose HasValue = false, and return it
}
```

My attempt, which doesn't work (it throws a `NullReferenceException`) as there's no default constructor:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Create(typeof(Nullable<int>)));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

//type is guaranteed to be implement from Nullable<>
public static object Create(Type type)
{
    //Instantatie a Nullable<T> with reflection whose HasValue = false, and return it
    return type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Given a type parameter which is a `Nullable<>`, how can I create an instance of that type which has HasValue = false?

If you want a method with a signature of `object`, you just return `null`:

```
//type is guaranteed to be implement from Nullable<>
public static object Create(Type type)
{
    return null;
}
```

That will always be the boxed representation of any nullable type value where `HasValue` is null. In other words, the method is pointless... you might as well just use the `null` literal:

```
var i = (int?) null;
```

Of course, if `type` isn't guaranteed to be nullable value type, you might want to conditionalize the code... but it's important to understand that there's no such thing as an *object* representation of a `Nullable<T>` value. Even for non-null values, the boxed representation is the boxed representation of the *non-nullable* type:

```
int? x = 5;
object y = x; // Boxing
Console.WriteLine(y.GetType()); // System.Int32; nullability has vanished
```

Comment: The reason I need to do this is because I need to support calls to methods on Nullable<> when the instance is null. Reflection returns `null` when retrieving values for Nullable<> properties which have HasValue = false, which of course differs from the behaviour in 'normal' compiled code.

Comment: @IanNewson: You haven't really given any context here, but you need to understand the boxing rules for nullable value types.

Comment: The context is that I'm responsible for a LINQ provider which for performance reasons evaluates a lot of code in the expressions itself, rather than compiling the expression to a `Func` or similar. Calling methods on null `Nullable<>`s seems to be an edge case not handled by the reflection API, i.e. calling `getValueOrDefault.Invoke(aNullNullable)` throws. I'm trying to work around this.

Comment: @IanNewson: Without seeing any of your actual reflection code, it's hard to tell what you're seeing. It sounds like you should ask a new question about that, based on the understanding that a boxed nullable value is either "the boxed underlying value" or "a null reference".

Answer (score 0):

**Highly dangerous** (and not recommended for non-testing purposes) is to use [SharpUtils](https://github.com/IllidanS4/SharpUtils)' method `UnsafeTools.Box<T>(T? nullable)`. It bypasses the normal boxing of nullable types, which boxes their value or returns null, and instead creates an actual instance of `Nullable<T>`. Note that working with such an instance can be extremely buggy.

```
public static object Create<T>() where T : struct //T must be a normal struct, not nullable
{
    return UnsafeTools.Box(default(T?));
}
```

Comment: So if you call `Create<int>().GetType()` will that return `typeof(int?)` effectively? Interesting...

Comment: @Jon Exactly. Is is even possible to cast it back to `(int?)`.