# Nullable<long> is not Nullable<long> after assignment from long

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I have an unexpected behaviour with nullables on primitives.

My test code:

```
Nullable<long> value = long.Parse("5");
Type type = value.GetType();
// at this Point type is System.Int64 and not Nullable<System.Int64>
```

Is there any possibility, where `value` stays a `Nullable<System.Int64>` and does not get converted to a regular `long`?

Comment: `long.Parse` returns a `long`, not a `long?` - allways. So surely the answer is: no. Why you even use `long?`?

Comment: well, `long.Parse` returns a `long` and not a `long?` - so the actual content of the variable _is_ `long`. that being said: if you value _were_ `null`, you couldn't call `.GetType()` on it, anyway.

Comment: Well value is strongly typed as Nullable<long>. I would expect to use a Nullable<long> after the declaration and not a long.

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#how-to-identify-a-nullable-value-type) documentation to read *How to identify a nullable value type*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int64.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Int64_Parse_System_String_) `long.Parse` returns `long`, not `long?`.

```
public static long Parse (string s);
```

You can of course **convert** that to a `long?`, but that doesn´t change that statement.

```
long a = long.Parse("5");
Nullable<long> n = a; // convert to long?
```

So in short there´s no way `long.Parse` will **ever** return something different than a `long`. Even when you provide some invalid input:

```
long a = long.Parse("Hello"); //throws FormatException
```

Calling `GetType` on your variable will give you the **runtime**-type, not the compile-time one. As `Parse` returns a `long` at runtime, `GetType` surely does also.

Comment: This is wrong. It's being assigned to a `long?`

Comment: @Charlieface sure, but before we can **asign** it, we have to **convert** it.

Comment: OK but you have not explained why `GetType` returns `long` not `long?`

Comment: @Charlieface see my last statement...

Comment: You *still* have not explained why `long?.GetType()` returns `long`

Comment: @Charlieface Sure I did: the **value** simply **is not** `long?`, but `long`.

Comment: Well in this case if you call GetType() on n, the resulting type will still be System.Int64 and not Nullable<System.Int64> right? So there is no chance to determine during runtime if n is a Nullable if it has a value set?

Comment: @ArndtBieberstein Yes, `GetType` will allways give you the type of the **value**, regardless on how you declared it at **compile-time**.

Comment: Wow didn't expect that. I thought it would stay strongly typed.

Answer (score 3):

No. You have already assigned it to a `long?` variable.

When you call `GetType()`, this function is defined on `System.Object`. Therefore to call it, we must box the value.

> You can see this by viewing the generated MSIL instructions for the `GetType()` call:
> `box System.Nullable<System.Int64>`
> `call System.Object.GetType`
> So when it is boxed it actually pushes the `long?` on the stack, and the boxing only gives us a boxed `long`

Hence the resulting value, in the case of a nullable, is the base type (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775582/how-is-the-boxing-unboxing-behavior-of-nullablet-possible) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#boxing-and-unboxing)).

In this instance, there is no reason to call `GetType` anyway, because we **know** it's a `long?`

Comment: _When you call GetType(), this function is defined on System.Object. Therefore to call it, we must box the value._ this is non-intuitive, and even if I comprehend it perfectly, and I comprehend why it happens, still it remains non-intuitive :-)

Comment: 100% agreed, `Nullable<>` (and valuetype in general) semantics leave what to be desired

Comment: "because we know it's a long?" No, it´s **not** a `long?` - at least not at runtime, which `GetType` will cover.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It is a `long?` after assignment to a `long?` variable. It is then boxed **afterwards**, converting it back to a boxed `long`

Comment: `5` is not `long?`, it is **assignable** to it, though. So no, the value is still a `long`. There´s a huge difference between how you **declare** a variable and what it **contains** at runtime - and *that's what `GetType` will cover.

Comment: **Rad my answer**, boxing converts it **back** into a `long`. The variable is 100% a `long?`. See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXkNLC)

Comment: boxing converts to long? Eeehm, no... that is **un-boxing**. Btw: your fiddle doesn´t handle `GetType`.

Comment: See [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#boxing-and-unboxing). You can also see the IL generated for `((long?)5).GetType()` is `newobj System.Nullable<System.Int64>..ctor      box System.Nullable<System.Int64>     call System.Object.GetType` so it is definitely a `long?` on the stack until the `box` instruction