# what is faster (obj as Struct != null) or (obj is Struct) in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

what is faster

```
AnswerClass ansClass = obj as AnswerClass;
if(ansClass != null){
    //use ansClass directly
}
```

or

```
if(obj is AnswerClass ){
   AnswerClass ansClass = (AnswerClass) obj;
   //use ansClass now
}
```

In C#.net.

I have looked around but cannot find anything that answers this, does anybody here know?

I have edited to better explain the question I have, It is comparing 'as' then null check, then use, with 'is' then a direct Cast?

Comment: There's very useful class (`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`) for profiling things like this.

Comment: If this is really the bottleneck for performance in your application, you've got deeper issues.

Comment: You should read this : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: Try it. Run each in a loop (several million times around the loop), time them and find out for yourself.

Comment: why not `var answerStruct=obj as AnswerStruct; if (answerStruct!=null) {` no need for additional cast inside?

Comment: Well you can Time it out and find which one is faster ! !

Comment: @BobVale If `AnswerStruct` is really a reference type (like `class`, `interface`, `delegate` type, or array type), that's the nicest way in my opinion. But if `AnswerStruct` is a value type (like **`struct`** or `enum`), see my comment to dtb's answer.

Answer (score 6):

The `as` operator doesn't work with value types (`struct`s), so if you have

```
struct SomeStruct { }

object obj = new SomeStruct();
```

then the only option  to find out the type and unbox the value is

```
if (obj is SomeStruct)
{
    SomeStruct val = (SomeStruct)obj;
```

Comment: Correct. He could say `var answer = obj as AnswerStruct?; if (answer.HasValue) { ... }` but that's slower according to [Performance surprise with “as” and nullable types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/).

Answer (score 2):

**Both of the them are same, there is no difference** *(I hope its a class not a struct, in your question, otherwise it won't compile)*

Suppose you have:

```
class Test
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int SomeOther { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object obj = new Test();

        if (obj as Test != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test1");
        }

        if (obj is Test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test2");
        }

    }
```

If you view the code in [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object obj = new Test();
    if (obj is Test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test1");
    }
    if (obj is Test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test2");
    }
}
```

Here is the IL from ildasm

.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed

```
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       43 (0x2b)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] object obj)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void ILTest.Test::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  isinst     ILTest.Test
  IL_000c:  brfalse.s  IL_0018
  IL_000e:  ldstr      "test1"
  IL_0013:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0018:  ldloc.0
  IL_0019:  isinst     ILTest.Test
  IL_001e:  brfalse.s  IL_002a
  IL_0020:  ldstr      "test2"
  IL_0025:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_002a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: It is also the same for a struct?

Comment: @Kobi, I haven't tried it with struct,I believe I won't be able to use `!= null` with struct/value types. Also the keyword `as` will not work with value types

Answer (score 1):

When you want to check if `obj` is an `AnswerStruct`, how on Earth can you go clearer than:

```
if(obj is AnswerStruct)
```

If you are so concerned about microoptimisations, the first thing you should do is use a non-managed language. This aside from the fact that there is actually nothing faster than this piece of code and that, as [dtb wrote in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009842/what-is-faster-obj-as-struct-null-or-obj-is-struct-in-c-net/13009916#13009916), sometimes this is the only variation that will work. Do not sacrifice clarity for a worthless gain in speed, specially when there is no gain at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you meant to talk about classes**

They're equivalent, as they compile down to the same bytecode.

The `as` operator simply calls the `isinst` operator, while the `is` operator calls `isinst`, and then checks for null, just like you did.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two ways but the same calling process both take the same time ( as operator calls the `isinst` operator and same with is operator calls `isinst` and both will check for null).