# Change all TextBox BorderStyle in my winform

Tags: c#, textbox

How do i change all the borderstyle of textbox in winform by foreach

or something shorter then listing every textbox and change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the form's controls:

```
foreach(Control c in myForm.Controls)
{ 
    if(c is TextBox)
    { 
         ((TextBox)c).BorderStyle = yourStyle;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

if you have some containers that can contains TextBoxes (such as panels, tabControls, ecc..) you can iterate recursively:

```
private void checkControl(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        var textBox = c as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        else
            checkControl(c);
    }
}
```

and initially call the method with:

```
checkControl(this);
```

Comment: The only right answer, because you should always use recursion (just in case). However code is a bit unclear without `is`. Another thing is that you may have certain `TextBox`'es which you don't want to *touch*. Then you can use `Tag` to *mark* something. In fact with the use of `Tag` you don't even need to check is it a `TextBox` or not.

Comment: @Sinatr About the `is` usage I think that this is a good practice in terms of performance (refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13405826/838405) for more information). You are right about the Tag but I don't know the OP's intentions.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SetTextBoxBorderStyle(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach(Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        if(c is TextBox)
           (c as TextBox).BorderStyle = yourStyle;
        else
           SetTextBoxBorderStyle(c);
    }
}
```

Invoke it in your form like this:

```
SetTextBoxBorderStyle(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setAllTextBoxs(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        if (c is TextBox)
            (c as TextBox).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        else if(c.HasChildren)
            setAllTextBoxs(c);
}
```

Lambda equivalent... old faithful one liner XD

```
public void setAllTextBoxs(Control control)
{
    control.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToList().ForEach(c => { if (c is TextBox) (c as TextBox).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle; else if (c.HasChildren) setAllTextBoxs(c); });
}
```

and call it like this:

```
setAllTextBoxs(this);
```