# In C#, how can I tell whether a generic type, T, is (not implements!) an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface

**Edit**: I made a mistake an the premise was wrong. typeof(T).IsClass does indeed work - as does typeof(T)IsInterface, as was pointed out.

Say I have this method:

```
public T GetService<T>() where T : IService
```

I want to test whether the generic type, T, was sent into this method as an interface, rather than as a class. In other words, I want to differentiate between a call from `MyClass.GetService<IService>()` and `MyClass.GetService<ImplementingClass>()`. How can I do this?

I tried using `is object`, and `is System.Object`, but it will not make this distinction. Using `typeof(T).IsClass` and `default(T).IsClass` also don't work, because, respectively, the the System.Type return type is always a class, and because IsClass isn't available to a default T.

How else can I do this?

Comment: Have you try a simple cast and then check if null?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405714/is-versus-try-cast-with-null-check

Comment: In your case the object T always should implement the IService if not compiler exception will be thrown. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am not actually trying to find out whether T implements the interface or not; I want to prevent users of the class from calling this method using an implementation - they should be working with the interface return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check runtime like below.

```
typeof(T).IsInterface
```

[Please check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096568/how-can-i-use-interface-as-a-c-sharp-generic-type-constraint) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your case,typeof(T).IsClass does work

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my premise was wrong. This does indeed work:

```
typeof(T).IsClass
```

which returns false if an interface is specified.