# Can I cast from DBNull to a Nullable Bool in one line?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, nullable

I have a database query which will either return `NULL` or a boolean (bit) value.

I wish to store this value in a variable of type `Nullable<bool>` in C#.

I can't seem to find an acceptable mix of explict casts and conversions that do this in a simple way without Exceptions being thrown.

Can it be done in one readable line?

**EDIT:** Code as requested

```
private Nullable<bool> IsRestricted;
...//data access
IsRestricted = (bool?)DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(dataObj, "IsRestricted");
```

or perhaps

```
IsRestricted = (bool?)(bool)DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(dataObj, "IsRestricted");
```

Comment: could you show your problematic code ?

Comment: And the value representing _False_ and _True_.

Comment: If it's just a matter of coding style, write a `ToNullable` method.  Use [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/03/04/generic-conversion-for-dbnull-and-nullable-types.aspx) as a starting point.

Comment: Will the db query code really return `NULL`, or does it return `DBNull.Value`?

Comment: @bridge It will appear as type `DBNull` when in code.

Comment: Funny enough that Microsoft [describes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) `Nullable<T>` as a use-case for `NULL` DB column values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

assuming you have a datareader dr:

```
bool? tmp = Convert.IsDBNull(dr["dbnullValue"]) ? null: (bool?) dr["dbnullValue"];
```

---ADDED----

or maybe you can use the ?? if you don't have to check for DBNull but i'm not sure compiler will like this (i cannot test it now)

```
bool? tmp = dr["dbnullValue"] ?? (bool?) dr["dbnullValue"];
```

Comment: This looks to be what I want. Will test it.

Comment: Your second snippet won't compile. `??` doesn't know anything about `DBNull`.

Comment: Your first example does what I need - the second is one I tried without success.

Comment: the second snippet is in case you don't have to check for dbnull but only for null!

Comment: The first alternative is loooong, the second one doesn't seem to work. -1 I think answer of SLaks is better.

Comment: @giammin I think unsafe is to repeat twice the string with column name dr["column"]. If you make a typo, you have a problem.

Answer (score 6):

You could write `value as bool?`.
This will return `null` if `value` is not of type `bool`.

Note that [this is somewhat inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1583050/34397).

Comment: I don't like this, because it's unsafe. If something changes and the result is some other type, I think exception is much better than `null`.

Comment: @svick: Then you need more complexity: `value is DBNull ? null : (bool?)value`

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (reader.Read()) {
    bool? IsRestricted = (reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("IsRestricted"))) ? (null) : ((bool)reader.GetOrdinal("IsRestricted")));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use extension methods for this issue.

```
var isRestricted = dataRecord.GetNullableValue<bool>("IsRestricted");
```

There is code of GetNullableValue method:

```
    public static Nullable<TValue> GetNullableValue<TValue>(
        this IDataRecord record, 
        string name) where TValue : struct
    {
        return record.GetValue<TValue, Nullable<TValue>>(name);
    }
```

And there is also a simple code for GetValue method:

```
        private static TResult GetValue<TValue, TResult>(
        this IDataRecord record,
        string name)
    {
        var result = record[name];
        return !result.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? (TResult)result : default(TResult);
    }
```

Comment: Why `TValue` parameter on the `GetValue<TValue,TResult>` method? Also, why `Nullable<T>` rather than `T?` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following

`bool? myNullableBoolean = SqlConvert.ToType<bool?>(reader["myNullableBooleanColumn"]);`