# Code that intentionally fails

Tags: c#

Is it bad style and/or bad for performance to write code that you know might fail and ignore the exception? For example (in C#):

```
long l = 1;
try {
  l = (long)castObject;
} catch(InvalidCastException e) { }
```

In this scenario, the programmer doesn't particularly care whether or not an `InvalidCastException` is thrown.

Comment: I generally try to avoid swallowing exceptions as that's a bad practice to get into, even if it may not seem to be an issue in a particular instance.

Comment: Why not `long? v = castObject as long?; if (v.HasValue) l = v.Value;`?

Comment: @Tim you can't `as` to a value type like `long`, needs `long?` or `Nullable<long>` instead.

Comment: @Mephy: Note http://stackoverflow.com/q/1583050/34397

Comment: Side note: likely the problem is not in that piece of code , but rather in other code that uses non-generic collections or some other code that ignores type of objects... (in any case if you need to ignore particular exception you should catch just that exception)

Comment: @Mephy thanks for the info, I didn't know about using `?` for nullable types like that. @SLaks very good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do that.

- Exceptions incur a substantial performance hit.
- It will annoy developers who run with Break On Exceptions turned on.
  (which you should do to catch hidden bugs)
- It makes the intent less clear.  (why might it not be a `long`?)

Comment: In addition to the above, the `catch` can catch stuff that you probably don't want to hide, such as `OutOfMemoryException`, `Exception` and `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @Sam no, that's not correct as StackOverflowException cannot be caught. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: A cast operation can't throw that anyway.  (although a property setter could)

Comment: @SLaks true, it was more a general comment about that particular exception.

Comment: Regarding your point about the `try`-`catch` making the intent less clear, you could just encapsulate the code in a descriptively-named method or use a comment, so I don't think that aspect is necessarily a problem, especially if `try`-`catch` is the only way to do something due to the API you're working with.