# Is there a replacement for 'as' with value types?

Tags: c#, casting, value-type

I'm fully aware *why* `as`cannot be used for value types. However, the only replacement I am aware of is:

```
if (!(obj is MyValueType)) { // Type check #1
  // Exception or whatnot
}

var myValueType = (MyValueType)obj; // Type check #2
```

However, this code does the type check twice which has a performance cost, the same cost `as` came to solve for reference types.

My question: Is there any better performant mechanism / syntax for value types?

The only single type checking mechanism I can think of is `try/catch`, but that of course has a performance cost of its own, and I try to avoid exception-based programming when I can.

Comment: `this code does the type check twice which has a performance cost,` Ok why not omitting the first check at all, and let it throw `InvalidCastException` when the type is incorrect?

Comment: @Kilanny author dont want to use try catch exception-based programming.

Comment: @Kilanny that's a possibility but for consistency reasons you many times want to throw the expected/documented exception. For example, my code is implementing `IComparable`, which requires implementing CompareTo(object obj), and the `IComparable` documentation specifically states that implementers should throw `ArgumentException` (which makes sense). Pretty much the same reason why you null check method arguments and throw `ArgumentNullException` instead of just letting your code throw `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: It is trade-off between performance and consistency. Author should decide. I don't even believe it would be costly to check twice

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? Otherwise I cannot know the issue you found with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* use:

```
var maybeValueType = obj as MyValueType?;
if (maybeValueType != null)
{
    // Use maybeValueType.Value
}
```

However, this [performs *worse* than `is` + casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types) - or at least has in the past.

It's possible that C# 7 will fix this with:

```
if (obj is MyValueType value)
{
    // Use value here
}
```

... but obviously until C# 7 is more pinned down, it's not certain.

Comment: Suspected so. Thanks Jon! Will accept as soon as SO lets me.