# Registering for an event of a subclass of a field c#

Tags: c#, oop, events

Let me model my question like this.

I have a hierarchy where `Dog`, `Cat`, `Bird` are subclasses of the abstract class `Animal`. `Bird` has a new event `BirdEvent` that is not (and should not be) in `Animal`.

I have a class `MyObject` that has a field of type `Animal` (to take advantage of polymorphism). Let's assume that some instances of `MyObject` will fill their `Animal` field with `Bird` and others with `Cat` or `Dog`. If the `Animal` field contains an instance of `Bird`, I want to register for its `BirdEvent`. But as the field is of type `Animal`, it obviously cannot have a `BirdEvent`.

```
MyObject myObject= new Myobject();

if (myObject.Animal is Bird)
{
     myObject.Animal.BirdEvent += reactToBirdEvent;   
}
```

Is there a way I could reach BirdEvent? Or quite possibly, is my design flawed somewhere I didn't see?

Comment: You can cast it safely to `Bird`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) it to `Bird`:

```
MyObject myObject= new Myobject();

if (myObject.Animal is Bird)
{
      ((Bird)myObject.Animal).BirdEvent += reactToBirdEvent;   
}
```

Comment: Okay, this kind of casting was new to me. Thank you!

Comment: @purrduc Note that this will actually cast the object twice, once for `is` and then  again for the explicit cast.  To avoid that it's better to use `as` and a `null` check.

Comment: Thx for your edit @TimSchmelter, it is more complete now

Comment: @juharr: [true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/284240), but not for performance reasons. Actually, if `myObject` was a value type, the `as`+`null`-check is even [less efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types) than the `is` + explicit cast.

Comment: @juharr Noted, thanks. As long as there is any other indication that the object is of type `Bird`, the `is` can be left out.

Answer (score 2):

Simply cast your instance to `Bird` using the [safe-cast-approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/2528063):

```
Bird myBird = myObject.Animal as Bird;
if (myBird != null)
{
      myBird.BirdEvent += reactToBirdEvent;   
}
```