# Why does 'unbox.any' not provide a helpful exception text the way 'castclass' does?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil, unboxing

To illustrate my question, consider these trivial examples (C#):

```
object reference = new StringBuilder();
object box = 42;
object unset = null;

// CASE ONE: bad reference conversions (CIL instrcution 0x74 'castclass')
try
{
  string s = (string)reference;
}
catch (InvalidCastException ice)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ice.Message); // Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' to type 'System.String'.
}
try
{
  string s = (string)box;
}
catch (InvalidCastException ice)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ice.Message); // Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
}

// CASE TWO: bad unboxing conversions (CIL instrcution 0xA5 'unbox.any')
try
{
  long l = (long)reference;
}
catch (InvalidCastException ice)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ice.Message); // Specified cast is not valid.
}
try
{
  long l = (long)box;
}
catch (InvalidCastException ice)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ice.Message); // Specified cast is not valid.
}
try
{
  long l = (long)unset;
}
catch (NullReferenceException nre)
{
  Console.WriteLine(nre.Message); // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
}
```

So in the cases where we attempt a reference conversion (corresponding to CIL instruction `castclass`), the exception thrown contains an excellent message of the form:

> Unable to cast object of type 'X' to type 'Y'.

Empirical evidence shows that this text message is often extremely helpful for the (experienced or inexperienced) developer (bug fixer) who needs to deal with the problem.

In contrast, the message we get when an attempted unboxing (`unbox.any`) fails, is rather non-informative. Is there any technical reason why this must be so?

> Specified cast is not valid. [NOT HELPFUL]

In other words, why do we not receive a message like (my words):

> Unable to unbox an object of type 'X' into a value of type 'Y';
>   the two types must agree.

respectively (my words again):

> Unable to unbox a null reference into a value of the non-nullable type 'Y'.

So to repeat my question: Is it "accidental" that the error message in one case is good and informative, and in the other case is poor? Or is there a technical reason why it would be impossible, or prohibitively difficult, for the runtime to provide details of the actual types encountered in the second case?

(I have seen a couple of threads here on SO that I am sure would never have been asked if the exception text for failed unboxings had been better.)

---

Update: Daniel Frederico Lins Leite's answer led to him opening an issue on the CLR Github (see below). This was discovered to be a duplicate of an earlier issue (raised by Jon Skeet, people almost guessed it!). So there was no good reason for the poor exception message, and people had already fixed it in the CLR. So I was not the first to wonder about this. We can look forward to the day when this improvement ships in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Jon [already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types).  Roughly.  Same reason, this had to generate compact and fast code back in the .NET 1.x days.  If you want a nice exception message then you have to write the code, `Convert.ToInt64(reference)`.  Still very compact, not as fast.

Comment: @HansPassant So the question you link is about why the pattern `var nullable = box as int?; if (nullable.HasValue) { /* use nullable.Value */ }` is much slower than `if (box is int) { var value = (int)box; /* use value */ }`. So I know the CIL instruction `unbox.any` which is used in the latter example, will be fast because no copying is involved. And it had to be fast in those .NET 1 days when simple values were boxed in non-generic collections all the time. __But how does it answer my question?__ In the "branch" where the type check has failed, can't we put more details into the exception?

Comment: Also, the `castclass` CIL instruction is expected to be incredibly fast, and it had to be so fast in those `ArrayList` and `Hashtable` days where collections were not strongly typed. `castclass` does no copying, just the type check and the reference goes to the same place. So where is the difference? `castclass` leads to a "rich" exception with from type and to type spelled out in the exception message, in the cases where the type check fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

I think that the runtime have all information needed to improve the message. Maybe some JIT developer could help, because it is needless to say that the JIT code is very sensitive and some times decisions are taken because of performance or security reasons, that are very difficult to an outsider to understand.

**Detailed Explanation**

To simplify the problem I changed the method to:

C#

```
void StringBuilderCast()
{
    object sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string s = (string)sbuilder;
}
```

IL

```
.method private hidebysig 
    instance void StringBuilderCast() cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x214c
    // Code size 15 (0xf)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] object sbuilder,
        [1] string s
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: castclass [mscorlib]System.String
    IL_000d: stloc.1
    IL_000e: ret
} // end of method Program::StringBuilderCast
```

The important opcodes here are:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.castclass.aspx

And the general memory layout is:

```
Thread Stack                        Heap
+---------------+          +---+---+----------+
| some variable |    +---->| L | T |   DATA   |
+---------------+    |     +---+---+----------+
|   sbuilder2   |----+
+---------------+

T = Instance Type  
L = Instance Lock  
Data = Instance Data
```

So in this case the runtime knows that it has a pointer to a StringBuilder 
and it should cast it to a string. In this situation it has all the information
needed to give you the best exception as possible.

If we see at the JIT
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/vm/interpreter.cpp#L6137
we will se something like that

```
CORINFO_CLASS_HANDLE cls = GetTypeFromToken(m_ILCodePtr + 1, CORINFO_TOKENKIND_Casting  InterpTracingArg(RTK_CastClass));
Object * pObj = OpStackGet<Object*>(idx);
ObjIsInstanceOf(pObj, TypeHandle(cls), TRUE)) //ObjIsInstanceOf will throw if cast can't be done
```

if we dig into this method

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/vm/eedbginterfaceimpl.cpp#L1633

and the important part would be:

```
BOOL fCast = FALSE;
TypeHandle fromTypeHnd = obj->GetTypeHandle();
 if (fromTypeHnd.CanCastTo(toTypeHnd))
    {
        fCast = TRUE;
    }
if (Nullable::IsNullableForType(toTypeHnd, obj->GetMethodTable()))
    {
        // allow an object of type T to be cast to Nullable<T> (they have the same representation)
        fCast = TRUE;
    }
    // If type implements ICastable interface we give it a chance to tell us if it can be casted 
    // to a given type.
    else if (toTypeHnd.IsInterface() && fromTypeHnd.GetMethodTable()->IsICastable())
    {
    ...
    }
 if (!fCast && throwCastException) 
    {
        COMPlusThrowInvalidCastException(&obj, toTypeHnd);
    }
```

The important part here is the method that throws the exception. As you can see
it receives both the current object and the type that you trying to cast to.

At the end, the Throw method calls this method:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/vm/excep.cpp#L13997

```
COMPlusThrow(kInvalidCastException, IDS_EE_CANNOTCAST, strCastFromName.GetUnicode(), strCastToName.GetUnicode());
```

Wich gives you the nice exception message with the type names.

But when you are casting a object to a value type

C#

```
void StringBuilderToLong()
{
    object sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    long s = (long)sbuilder;
}
```

IL

```
.method private hidebysig 
    instance void StringBuilderToLong () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2168
    // Code size 15 (0xf)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] object sbuilder,
        [1] int64 s
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: unbox.any [mscorlib]System.Int64
    IL_000d: stloc.1
    IL_000e: ret
}
```

the important opcode here is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unbox_any.aspx

and we can see the UnboxAny behavior here
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/vm/interpreter.cpp#L8766

```
//GET THE BOXED VALUE FROM THE STACK
Object* obj = OpStackGet<Object*>(tos);

//GET THE TARGET TYPE METADATA
unsigned boxTypeTok = getU4LittleEndian(m_ILCodePtr + 1);
boxTypeClsHnd = boxTypeResolvedTok.hClass;
boxTypeAttribs = m_interpCeeInfo.getClassAttribs(boxTypeClsHnd);

//IF THE TARGET TYPE IS A REFERENCE TYPE
//NOTHING CHANGE FROM ABOVE
if ((boxTypeAttribs & CORINFO_FLG_VALUECLASS) == 0)
{
    !ObjIsInstanceOf(obj, TypeHandle(boxTypeClsHnd), TRUE)
}
//ELSE THE TARGET TYPE IS A REFERENCE TYPE
else
{
    unboxHelper = m_interpCeeInfo.getUnBoxHelper(boxTypeClsHnd);
    switch (unboxHelper)
        {
        case CORINFO_HELP_UNBOX:
                MethodTable* pMT1 = (MethodTable*)boxTypeClsHnd;
                MethodTable* pMT2 = obj->GetMethodTable();

                if (pMT1->IsEquivalentTo(pMT2))
                {
                    res = OpStackGet<Object*>(tos)->UnBox();
                }
                else
                {
                    CorElementType type1 = pMT1->GetInternalCorElementType();
                    CorElementType type2 = pMT2->GetInternalCorElementType();

                    // we allow enums and their primtive type to be interchangable
                    if (type1 == type2)
                    {
                          res = OpStackGet<Object*>(tos)->UnBox();
                    }
                }

        //THE RUNTIME DOES NOT KNOW HOW TO UNBOX THIS ITEM
                if (res == NULL)
                {
                    COMPlusThrow(kInvalidCastException);

                    //I INSERTED THIS COMMENTS
            //auto thCastFrom = obj->GetTypeHandle();
            //auto thCastTo = TypeHandle(boxTypeClsHnd);
            //RealCOMPlusThrowInvalidCastException(thCastFrom, thCastTo);
                }
                break;
        case CORINFO_HELP_UNBOX_NULLABLE:
                InterpreterType it = InterpreterType(&m_interpCeeInfo, boxTypeClsHnd);
                size_t sz = it.Size(&m_interpCeeInfo);
                if (sz > sizeof(INT64))
                {
                    void* destPtr = LargeStructOperandStackPush(sz);
                    if (!Nullable::UnBox(destPtr, ObjectToOBJECTREF(obj), (MethodTable*)boxTypeClsHnd))
                    {
                        COMPlusThrow(kInvalidCastException);
                    //I INSERTED THIS COMMENTS
            //auto thCastFrom = obj->GetTypeHandle();
            //auto thCastTo = TypeHandle(boxTypeClsHnd);
            //RealCOMPlusThrowInvalidCastException(thCastFrom, thCastTo);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    INT64 dest = 0;
                    if (!Nullable::UnBox(&dest, ObjectToOBJECTREF(obj), (MethodTable*)boxTypeClsHnd))
                    {
                        COMPlusThrow(kInvalidCastException);
                    //I INSERTED THIS COMMENTS
            //auto thCastFrom = obj->GetTypeHandle();
            //auto thCastTo = TypeHandle(boxTypeClsHnd);
            //RealCOMPlusThrowInvalidCastException(thCastFrom, thCastTo);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
}
```

Well... at least, it seems possible to give a better exception message.
If you remember when the exception had a nice message the call was:

```
COMPlusThrow(kInvalidCastException, IDS_EE_CANNOTCAST, strCastFromName.GetUnicode(), strCastToName.GetUnicode());
```

and the less inforative message it was:

```
COMPlusThrow(kInvalidCastException);
```

So I think that it is possible to improve the message doing

```
auto thCastFrom = obj->GetTypeHandle();
auto thCastTo = TypeHandle(boxTypeClsHnd);
RealCOMPlusThrowInvalidCastException(thCastFrom, thCastTo);
```

I have created the following issue on the coreclr github to see what is Microsoft developers opinions.

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/7655

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. It would be great if you created an issue on Github, then you could link to this Stack Overflow thread, and I could link from here to Github.

Comment: I have created the issue and inserted the link here. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There is an interesting comment to your Github issue.  I have appended an update to my question text.